# what is the use of toString() in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are the original reasons for ToString() in Java and .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307896/what-are-the-original-reasons-for-tostring-in-java-and-net)
>   [when to use toString() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329168/when-to-use-tostring-method)

what is main  use of toString() in java

Comment: See [What are the original reasons for ToString() in Java and .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307896/what-are-the-original-reasons-for-tostring-in-java-and-net)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329168/when-to-use-tostring-method

Answer (score 17):

As the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) says:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

You can use this for:

- logging
- debugging
- representing in UI

etc.

However, it is advisable that you use it only for internal purposes, like logging and debugging.

Comment: +1 especially for "it is advisable that you use it only for internal purposes, like logging and debugging". *Effective Java* (I forget which item exactly) gives some good examples as to why this is the case.

Comment: It pains me when StringBuffer or StringBuilder breaks this principle...

Comment: @Vincent, fair point. But there it's a different semantics, perhaps it should've been `buildString()` instead of `toString()`

Comment: toString() should not be used for representation in UI. Representation in a UI is more often than not dependent on context (such as user Locale). Also, what is useful for logging is often very different than what is useful (or understandable) for a user.

Answer (score 2):

The main use of `toString()` is allowing arbitrary objects to be printed or logged.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you come up with a String representation of your class, so you'll see meaningful values in your logs or when debugging instead of the default `YourClass@38c313`. This representation is completely arbitrary.

For details, have a look at Item 10 in [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), it has a couple of pretty good advices.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, sometimes it is useful to convert some object to a textual representation, and then define a constructor which can create an object out of this textual representation, something like

```
public Foo(String textualRep) {

}
```

I've seen this approach somewhere in used in the JDK but can't remember where.