# How to use the toString method in Java?

Tags: java

Can anybody explain to me the concept of the `toString()` method, defined in the `Object` class? How is it used, and what is its purpose?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329168/when-to-use-tostring-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887640/what-is-the-use-of-tostring-in-java

Comment: here is a quick trick/quick-implementation as well :     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [`Object.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) docs:

> Returns a string representation of the
>   object. In general, the `toString`
>   method returns a string that
>   "textually represents" this object.
>   The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is
>   easy for a person to read. It is
>   recommended that all subclasses
>   override this method.
>
> The `toString` method for class `Object`
>   returns a string consisting of the
>   name of the class of which the object
>   is an instance, the at-sign character
>   `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal
>   representation of the hash code of the
>   object. In other words, this method
>   returns a string equal to the value
>   of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Example:

```
String[] mystr ={"a","b","c"};
System.out.println("mystr.toString: " + mystr.toString());

output:- mystr.toString: [Ljava.lang.String;@13aaa14a
```

Comment: The main purpose is to override it in subclasses. I think answers from @stephen  and Andreas_D  are  better than accepted answer.

Answer (score 40):

Use of the `String.toString`:

Whenever you require to explore the constructor called value in the `String` form, you can simply use `String.toString`...
for an example...

```
package pack1;

import java.util.*;

class Bank {

    String n;
    String add;
    int an;
    int bal;
    int dep;

    public Bank(String n, String add, int an, int bal) {

        this.add = add;
        this.bal = bal;
        this.an = an;
        this.n = n;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name of the customer.:" + this.n + ",, "
                + "Address of the customer.:" + this.add + ",, " + "A/c no..:"
                + this.an + ",, " + "Balance in A/c..:" + this.bal;
    }
}

public class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Bank> l = new LinkedList<Bank>();

        Bank b1 = new Bank("naseem1", "Darbhanga,bihar", 123, 1000);
        Bank b2 = new Bank("naseem2", "patna,bihar", 124, 1500);
        Bank b3 = new Bank("naseem3", "madhubani,bihar", 125, 1600);
        Bank b4 = new Bank("naseem4", "samastipur,bihar", 126, 1700);
        Bank b5 = new Bank("naseem5", "muzafferpur,bihar", 127, 1800);
        l.add(b1);
        l.add(b2);
        l.add(b3);
        l.add(b4);
        l.add(b5);
        Iterator<Bank> i = l.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    }

}
```

... copy this program into your Eclipse, and run it... you will get the ideas about `String.toString`...

Comment: I hope you're aware that `toString` is not intended and not suitable for UI purposes.

Comment: @Powerslave then explain why all Swing components are using `toString` to display an object in the GUI? If I have a rich object and I want to show it in a GUI, then no, I don't create an extra renderer for it nor do I extract a string property out of the object to use that in the GUI, I keep it simple and implement `toString` to be able to circumvent all that overhead. If you want to do this in a more clean way, create a wrapper class which is dedicated for UI purposes, and implements its `toString` method to return a string property of the wrappee.

Comment: @Timmos If your friends jumped off a bridge would you follow? Just because the Swing developers use (read; abuse) the toString function doesn't mean you should too.

Comment: It's by far the most easiest approach for getting the job done, given you keep using the default Swing API. If you want custom rendering, fine, install a custom renderer on your component. If you just want to display an object represented by a String, then implementing toString() is way easier compared to a custom renderer, which has all kind off pitfalls to do it right. I think that your comparison with jumping off a bridge is odd.

Answer (score 39):

The `toString()` method returns a *textual* representation of an object. A basic implementation is already included in `java.lang.Object` and so because all objects inherit from `java.lang.Object` it is guaranteed that every object in Java has this method.

Overriding the method is always a good idea, especially when it comes to debugging, because debuggers often show objects by the result of the `toString()` method. So use a meaningful implementation but use it for *technical* purposes. The application logic should use getters:

```
public class Contact {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  public Contact (String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
  public String getLastName() {return lastName;}

  public String getContact() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "["+getContact()+"]";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

It may optionally have uses within the context of an application but far more often it is used for debugging purposes. For example, when you hit a breakpoint in an IDE, it's far easier to read a meaningful `toString()` of objects than it is to inspect their members.

There is no set requirement for what a `toString()` method should do. By convention, most often it will tell you the name of the class and the value of pertinent data members. More often than not, `toString()` methods are auto-generated in IDEs.

Relying on particular output from a `toString()` method or parsing it within a program is a bad idea. Whatever you do, don't go down that route.

Comment: could you elaborate on your last statement ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeCaruana The `toString` method is intended for **debugging and logging**, for internal use by programmers & system administrators. The `toString` method is not intended for presentation to the user, nor is it intended to provide a reliable structured value suitable for parsing. The implementation of `toString` tends to change as its containing class evolves. For presentation to user, add a method like `getDisplayName`. For structured parseable content, add a method whose name indicates the specification of that structure such as `formatDairyAssociationQuarterlyReportItem`.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeCaruana The contract promised by the Javadoc for [`Object::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) states: *The string output is not necessarily stable over time or across JVM invocations.* So by definition, not suitable for reliable parsing.

Answer (score 12):

[toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returns a string/textual representation of the object.
Commonly used for diagnostic purposes like debugging, logging etc., the toString() method is used to read meaningful details about the object.

It is automatically invoked when the object is passed to println, print, printf, String.format(), assert or the string concatenation operator.

The default implementation of toString() in class Object returns a string consisting of the class name of this object followed by @ sign and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of this object using the following logic,

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

For example, the following

```
public final class Coordinates {

    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Coordinates(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(1, 2);
        System.out.println("Bourne's current location - " + coordinates);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Bourne's current location - Coordinates@addbf1 //concise, but not really useful to the reader
```

Now, overriding toString() in the Coordinates class as below,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
}
```

results in

```
Bourne's current location - (1.0, 2.0) //concise and informative
```

The usefulness of overriding toString() becomes even more when the method is invoked on collections containing references to these objects. For example, the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coordinates bourneLocation = new Coordinates(90, 0);
    Coordinates bondLocation = new Coordinates(45, 90);
    Map<String, Coordinates> locations = new HashMap<String, Coordinates>();
    locations.put("Jason Bourne", bourneLocation);
    locations.put("James Bond", bondLocation);
    System.out.println(locations);
}
```

prints

```
{James Bond=(45.0, 90.0), Jason Bourne=(90.0, 0.0)}
```

instead of this,

```
{James Bond=Coordinates@addbf1, Jason Bourne=Coordinates@42e816}
```

Few implementation pointers,

1. *You should almost always override the toString() method.* One of the cases where the override wouldn't be required is utility classes that group static utility methods, in the manner of [java.util.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html). The case of override being not required is pretty intuitive; almost always you would know.
2. The string returned should be concise and informative, ideally self-explanatory.
3. At least, the fields used to establish equivalence between two different objects i.e. the fields used in the [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method implementation should be spit out by the toString() method.
4. Provide accessors/getters for all of the instance fields that are contained in the string returned. For example, in the Coordinates class,

   ```
   public double getX() {
       return x;
   }
   public double getY() {
       return y;
   }
   ```

A comprehensive coverage of the toString() method is in Item 10 of the book, Effective Java™, Second Edition, By Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you access an Object (not being a String) in a String context then the toString() is called under the covers by the compiler.

This is why

```
Map map = new HashMap();
System.out.println("map=" + map);
```

works, and by overriding the standard toString() from Object in your own classes, you can make your objects useful in String contexts too.

(and consider it a black box!  Never, ever use the contents for anything else than presenting to a human)

Answer (score 4):

Correctly overridden toString method can help in logging and debugging of Java.

Answer (score 4):

**Coding:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<Student> a = new ArrayList<Student>();
        a.add(new Student("Steve", 12, "Daniel"));
        a.add(new Student("Sachin", 10, "Tendulkar"));

        System.out.println(a);

        display(a);

    }

    static void display(ArrayList<Student> stu) {

        stu.add(new Student("Yuvi", 12, "Bhajji"));

        System.out.println(stu);

    }

}
```

**Student.java:**

```
public class Student {

    public String name;

    public int id;

    public String email;

    Student() {

    }

    Student(String name, int id, String email) {

        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;

    }

     public String toString(){           //using these toString to avoid the output like this [com.steve.test.Student@6e1408, com.steve.test.Student@e53108]
          return name+" "+id+" "+email;     
         }  


    public String getName(){

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){

        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getId(){

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){

        this.id=id;
    }

    public String getEmail(){

        return email;

    }

    public void setEmail(String email){

        this.email=email;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> [Steve 12 Daniel, Sachin 10 Tendulkar]
>
> [Steve 12 Daniel, Sachin 10 Tendulkar, Yuvi 12 Bhajji]

If you are not used toString() in Pojo(Student.java) class,you will get an output like `[com.steve.test.Student@6e1408, com.steve.test.Student@e53108]`.To avoid these kind of issue we are using toString() method.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what cletus answered with regards to debugging, it is used whenever you output an object, like when you use

```
 System.out.println(myObject);
```

or

```
System.out.println("text " + myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of toString is to generate a String representation of an object, means the return value is always a String. In most cases this simply is the object's class and package name, but on some cases like StringBuilder you will got actually a String-text.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * This toString-Method works for every Class, where you want to display all the fields and its values
 */
public String toString() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields(); //Get all fields incl. private ones

    for (Field field : fields){

        try {

            field.setAccessible(true);
            String key=field.getName();
            String value;

            try{
                value = (String) field.get(this);
            } catch (ClassCastException e){
                value="";
            }

            sb.append(key).append(": ").append(value).append("\n");

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you learn Python first and then Java. I think it plays the same role as [`__str__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448175/confused-about-str-in-python) method in Python, it is a [magic method](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php) like `__dict__()` and `__init__()` but to refer to a string representing the the object.

Answer (score 0):

the `toString()` converts the specified object to a string value.