# set method and incrementing

Tags: java

When setting new section I need to keep track of the counters.
for example if m1 is Brass and I use setSection(Strings);
I want it to Brass-- and Strings++
But I'm not sure how to do it with if statments 
and im not sure if getSection()toString() would get me the original section or not

```
/**This function sets a musician's Orchestra Section. 
 @param section  is a SymphonySection indicating the musician's Orchestra Section.*/

 public void setSection(SymphonySection section) {
    this.section = section;

    if (getSection().toString().equals( "Strings" )){
        Strings--;
    }
    else if (getSection().toString().equals( "Brass" )){
        Brass--;
    }
    else if (getSection().toString().equals( "Conductor" )){
        Conductor--;
    }
    else if (getSection().toString().equals( "Percussion" )){
        Percussion--;
    }
    else if (getSection().toString().equals( "WoodWinds" )){
        WoodWinds--;
    }

    if (section.toString().equals( "Strings" )){
        Strings++;
    }
    else if (section.toString().equals( "Brass" )){
        Brass ++;
    }
    else if (section.toString().equals( "Conductor" )){
        Conductor ++;
    }
    else if (section.toString().equals( "Percussion" )){
        Percussion ++;
    }
    else if (section.toString().equals( "WoodWinds" )){
        WoodWinds ++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind to use switch case ?

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob   no switch would be fine im just not sure if im getting the original section correct or not

Comment: @Moe: please hover over the homework tag, or actually go read its tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

1. Does your `SymphonySection` class have a `toString` method where it returns the section name? If not you need to implement this so that it returns the section name, e.g. Brass, Strings etc. Check here [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java) to implement in the `SymphonySection` class
2. I would suggest using a switch (which as of Java 7 supports Strings) statement to neaten things up a tad, or a map as suggested by Peter Lawrey
3. Please also take a look at Java naming conventions, [here](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), to make your code more readable. In the above case I am guessing `Strings`, `Brass`, etc. are variables of type `SymphonySection` and hence should have lower case first characters, e.g. `strings`, `brass`, etc. `WoodWinds`, would be `woodWinds` which follows the conventional camelcase coding style.

Hope this helps.

Hayden

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Map of counts for each section.

```
private final Map<SymphonySection, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
public void setSection(SymphonySection section) {
    if(section == this.section) return;

    count.put(this.section, count.get(this.section)-1);
    Integer prevCount = count.get(section)
    count.put(section, prevCount == null ? 1 : (prevCount+1));

    this.section = section;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but is there any way to do it with if statements like the way i wrote it? I know Maps but we did not do them yet in this class so I just prefer not to use them.

Comment: You can use reflection to get a field by name instead. As your fields match the `section.toString()` you can use this to look up the field. Using lots of if/else will work provided you don't change the old value until you have finished (as I did)

Answer (score 0):

**-** If you are having `Java 7`, and you want to go with the basics, then please use `switch`.

**-** Java 7 support `String` for `switch cases`.