# java print out class statement

Tags: java, class, printing

i am new to java and i have a simple question and i have this code

```
public abstract class Seq { int a, b, c;}

class For extends Seq{
public For( int first, int last, int step )
{
a=first;
b=last;
c=step;
}
```

and in the main i have:

```
For r1= new For(3, 4, 5);
```

what i want to do is that i want to add this statement in the main `System.out.print(r1);`
and i want this statement to print "your parameters: 3, 4, 5"

how can i do this?

Comment: I would take a read through [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Add a `toString` method in `For` as:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "your parameters: "+ a + ", "+ b+ ", "+c;
}
```

Comment: @user1763553: You need to accept the answers, if you like them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by implementing the `For` class' `toString` method:

```
public String toString ( )
{
    return "your parameters: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to override the `toString()` method and create another one that prints out the contents of `r1`.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return a + ", " + b + ", " + c;
}
```

Then it is simply:

`System.out.println("Your parameters: " + r1.toString());`