# Default Get method in custom java class

Tags: java, getter-setter

java n00b here.

I have a custom Data type defined like this:

```
public class MyData{
    int value;
    int type;
    String name;

    public MyData(int newValue, int newType, string newName)
    {
        value = newValue;
        type  = newType;
        name  = newName;
    }
}
```

When I call an instance of this class, I want it to evaluate to the value property, like this:

```
myData dataInstance = new myData(100,3,"customData");
System.out.println(dataInstance); // should print "100"
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: Yes use the toString method. Also class level fields should normally be declared private (e.g. private int value;)

Comment: Fix your sytnax errors (`String` instead of `string`), follow the Java naming conventions (`MyData` instead of `myData`) and override the `toString()` method. Then it will be achieved.

Comment: @jlordo pardon my ignorance, I usually never code in Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `System.out.println` with an object, it's going to call the `toString()` method - so you just need to override that:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}
```

Also note that you should be more specific in your terminology. When you wrote:

> When I call an instance of this class

... that doesn't mean anything. You don't call an instance - you call a method *on* an instance. In this case, the method is `toString`.

Comment: So, I can't just reference the instance, and have a "catch-all" method execute that way? Overriding `toString()` seems like a fine solution, but what I'm looking for is, not having to explicitly call a method on the instance.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: As Jon explained, if you override `toString()`, you don't have to explicitly call it, it will be done automatically by `System.out.println(dataInstance);`

Comment: Thanks for this method, to be more clear, just add this override method in your customized class.