# Are there any standard interface for converting Object to String in Java?

Tags: java, generics, interface

It us useful to emulate lambda in Java but currently you must implement in-place class which implement some interface...

For example a `join` function may get **Stringator** interface, so can join any `List` or `Collection` regardless of contained object:

```
interface Stringator<T> { String toString(T t); }

public static <T> String join(Collection<T> col, String delim, Stringator<T> s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<T> iter = col.iterator();
    if (iter.hasNext())
        sb.append(s.toString(iter.next()));
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(delim);
        sb.append(s.toString(iter.next()));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I don't know any standard **Stringator** or **ToStringer** interface...

This `join` implementation can simplify beans manipulation. For exanple to get list of books:

```
List<Book> books = ...;
String list =
  join(books, ", ", new Stringator<Book>{ toString(Book b) {return b.getName();} });
```

Note that suggestion to use standard **toString** violate Java convention: `toString` for debugging (look for JavaDoc and Java lang spec)!

**UPDATE** Java already have interface which work in other direction - [PropertyEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html). Each it implementation can construct `Object` from `String`. I look for `String` from `Object`...

**UPDATE 2**. Many people think that I wrongly avoid `toString`. This is from Java 7 Lang Spec (section 6.1):

```
A method that converts its object to a particular format F should be named
toF. Examples are the method toString of class Object and the methods
toLocaleString and toGMTString of class java.util.Date.
```

So if I have Book objects, `toString` naturally must return ISBN, but that if I need to join book titles? That is why `toString` not so good and `java.text.Format.format` or other looks more natural.

Comment: about this "violate Java convention" thing, do you have a link for this? because i'm not seeing it in the language spec.

Comment: There's no concept of a standard string in the real-world is there?  So I don't see how this could ever exist within Java.  BigDecimal has some variations on toString(), like toEngineeringString() but there's no interface for it, I think you're just going to have to write your own!  Perhaps you might standardise by using something like JSON?

Comment: Please look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Comment: Since both the eclipse and netbeans IDEs have options that automatically generate `troString()` methods for you, I am suspicious about your claim it violates java conventions. If the language creators didn't want you to override it, they would have made it final.

Comment: @gavenkoa your link only mentions what the default `Object.toString()` does. It mentions nothing about overriding it for use in subclasses.

Comment: Java spec say about `textual representation` which is made by analogy like this do Python by `str`/`utf` and in another object systems... Debuggers usually use `toString()` to simplify identifying  object...

Comment: Although there are classes that use `toString` for debugging purposes only, like `java.awt.Point` and `java.awt.Color` (see javaDocs), there are also lots of classes that use it for other reasons (like `java.util.BigInteger` or `java.util.BigDecimal`). Also, the general description here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString() doesn't even mention debugging. A textual representation can be useful for several purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Override `toString()`, it does not violate any java conventions and is actually a recommended practice.

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. **It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method**.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Comment: Using separate interface force developers to implement method. `toString`
doesn't do any such enforcement. But in any
way thanks for interest to question. +1

Answer (score 1):

There is no ToStringer or similar interface in std java, you can define your own, and use

`String stringValue()`

which is analog to intValue() longValue() etc, often used in java

Answer (score 1):

There is `java.text.Format.format` but it's not very nice and is abstract class.

Java SE 8 will probably have a functor interface for transforming between two arbitrary types, one of which may be `String`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue with overriding `toString()` other than the fact that that gives you only **one** way of expressing your object as a string.  I think ganvenkoa is suggesting something that allows you to easily express it in custom ways. Imagine if you're dealing with a `Customer` object whose `toString()` returns `John Smith`, but when you're joining a bunch of customers using `join(...)`, you want the customer to be expressed as `Smith, John`.

One thing that I've used for that sort of thing is a utility such as `com.google.common.collect.Iterables.transform(Iterable)` (which in turn uses a `Function`) and pass the result of that to `com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Iterable)`.
I'm hoping that will become more elegant with Java 8