# Using constructors in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to learn more about constructors in Java.

Below is my code. I am trying to print an integer value (addition and subtraction) but  my output is some random digits.

```
public class MyNumber {

    private int number;

    public MyNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public MyNumber add(MyNumber another) {
        return new MyNumber(this.number + another.number);
    }

    public MyNumber sub(MyNumber another) {
        return new MyNumber(this.number - another.number);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyNumber myNumber = new MyNumber(2);
        MyNumber c = myNumber.add(myNumber);
        System.out.println(c);
        MyNumber d = myNumber.sub(myNumber);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
com.Packagename.MyNumber@7c6768
com.Packagename.MyNumber@1690726
```

Please advise. I am very new to Java and any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Override the `toString()` method to output `number`.

Comment: below is the out put iam getting                   com.Packagename.MyNumber@7c6768
com.Packagename.MyNumber@1690726

Comment: btw It would be useful for you to read Oracle's official Java tutorials, they are pretty good and quite easy to understand: [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `toString` method so `println` outputs number you want.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

`System.out.println` calls `toString()` on object passed as argument, default implementation of `toString()` from class `Object` returns this `com....ClassName@...` thing. You need to override it as shown above.

More information in [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Moreover, `toString()` is called when operator + is applied on object being concatenated to String.

```
String a = "b" + new Integer(1); // "b1"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but seeing as he is new, you might want to elaborate on why he would want to override the `toString()` method.

Comment: Might want to explain roughly what the hex digits, class name and '@' are doing.

Comment: I didn't realize that the default toString was related to the println output for the object but it makes sense because he is passing a object rather than a explicit string to println.  I learned something here... thanks.

Comment: i did tryied using toString but i did not inclue(Override) the method in my class that is why it did not work now i added the methos and i could able to see the results as intgers..Thank you so much

Comment: when i declare add methods as MyNumber(i.e with the constructor) what does it mean?

Comment: It means you are creating new object with new value (addition or subtraction) and then returning it to the caller. Object that the method was called on is not modified.

Comment: Override annotation is just for new compilers (Java 7) to tell them that we wanted to override some method. If we by mistake make a typo (tooString), it will tell us that we are not overriding any method.

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz, i understood now

Comment: @Grzegorz `@Override` has been around since Java 5, released in 2004, so it's not new at all. Its use on methods from interfaces was introduced in Java 6, but even that's from 2006, and that's not new either.

Answer (score 3):

Every Java object (for example `myNumber`) inherits from `java.lang.Object` and has a `toString()` method which is put to use when you call `System.out.println(myNumber);`. The `toString()` method in its default form prints the ([apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)) random data you saw. In order to print the value of the `number` variable contained in the `MyNumber` class you simply override the `toString()` method like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyNumber {

       private int number;

       public MyNumber(int number){
           this.number = number;
       }
       public int getNumber(){
           return number;
       }
       public MyNumber add(MyNumber another){
           return new MyNumber(this.number + another.number);
       }
       public MyNumber sub(MyNumber another) {
              return new MyNumber(this.number - another.number);
           }
       
       public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(number);
        }
       
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           MyNumber myNumber = new MyNumber(2);
           MyNumber c = myNumber.add(myNumber);
           System.out.println(c.toString());
           MyNumber d = myNumber.sub(myNumber);
           System.out.println(d.toString());
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much i could able to figure this out with the help of Grzegorz