# How can I print all content of an array in one line?

Tags: java

```
public class Myname {
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Letter s = new Letter(); s.setCaracter("s");
    Letter e = new Letter(); e.setCaracter("e");
    Letter a = new Letter(); a.setCaracter("a");
    Letter r = new Letter(); r.setCaracter("r");
    Letter y = new Letter(); y.setCaracter("y");
    Letter o = new Letter(); o.setCaracter("o");
    Letter u = new Letter(); u.setCaracter("u");
    Letter n = new Letter(); n.setCaracter("n");
    Letter g = new Letter(); g.setCaracter("g"); 

    Letter name[] = new Letter[10];

    name[0] = s;
    name[1] = e;
    name[2] = a;
    name[3] = r;
    name[4] = s;
    name[5] = y;
    name[6] = o;
    name[7] = u;
    name[8] = n;
    name[9] = g;


    System.out.println(nombre[0].);//HERE!

  }
}
```

I would like to know a way to print in console all the array name[], with all of his content. To see something like this:
 searsyoung

I have tried with:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theArray));
```

it prints strange things ---->`[Letter_Myname.Letter@1d5550d,...`

Comment: `Arrays.toString(elements)` gives result in form `[elements[0].toString(), elements[1].toString(),..., elements[size-1].toString()]` and `fullClassName@hexHashCode` is result of default `toString()` implementation inherited from Object class. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java) you can find some info about toString() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate the array.

```
for(Letter l : name){
 System.out.print(l);
}
```

In `Letter` implementation you have to override `toString()` like this

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return caracter;
}
```

If you don't override `toString` you will get superclass `toString` implementation
and then you have to do something tricky like this to get work **but is not recommended**.

```
 for(Letter l : name){
     System.out.print(l.getCaracter());
 }
```

Comment: In case OP didn't override `toString()` method in `Letter` class I would probably use `System.out.print(l.getCaracter())`

Comment: Wow, I just started with java, and this is very usefull info. Could you explain me how the for(Letter l : name) works? thanks

Comment: @user2716652 it's `for each` loop introduce in Java 1.5 for more information read here [how does for each loop works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, you could do something like this:

```
Arrays.asList(name).forEach(System.out::print);
```

In case you did not override the `toString()` method, you could try this:

```
Arrays.asList(name).forEach(l -> System.out.print(l.getCaracter()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest introducing another class `Word` to encapsulate things some more. The advantage this has over other approaches is that it would blend seamlessly if and when you extend your program to `Sentence` and `Paragraph` classes.

```
Letter[] name = new Letter[10];

// name[i] = ...

Word fname = new Word(name);
System.out.println(fname); // searsyoung

// Check the Letter class updates below
System.out.println(new Word(new Letter('J'), new Letter('o'),
                            new Letter('h'), new Letter('n'))); // John
```

*Word Class*

```
public class Word {

    private Letter[] letters;

    // makes use of var-args
    public Word(Letter... word) {
        this.letters = word;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Letter l : letters) {
            sb.append(l);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

*Letter Class*

```
public class Letter {

    private char c; // Prefer char over String

    public Letter(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Letter() { // use new Letter('c') directly
    } // instead of two steps: new Letter(); setCaracter();

    public void setCaracter(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public char getCaracter() {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Character.toString(c);
    }

}
```

Since, you've provided both `Word#toString()` as well as `Letter#toString()` implementations; you can simply print any `Word` without looping now. The looping still happens but the class takes upon itself to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Three other solutions are possible in addition to foreach :

- For Loop
- Using an iterator
- While Loop

**Using for Loop:**

```
 for (int i=0;i<name.length;i++)  System.out.print(name[i]);
```

In this case you need to define `toString()` in your Letter class or a getter getCaracter() that return the value or your caracter.

And then it become:

```
 for (int i=0;i<name.length;i++)  System.out.print(name[i].getCaracter());
```

Both `toString()` and `getCaracter()` return same variable your caracter but toString is prefered because it's called by default when you print an object.

**An other way is to use an Iterator** :

First we transform our `name` Array to arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Letter> listLetters = new ArrayList<Letter>( Arrays.asList(name) );
```

And then we iterate over it using iterator():

```
 Iterator itr = listLetters.iterator(); 

 while(itr.hasNext()) {

   Letter letter = itr.next(); 
   System.out.print(letter);

}
```

**Using While Loop:**

```
 int i=0;
 while (i<name.length)  {    
     System.out.print(name[i].getCaracter());
     i++;  
  }
```

**Using foreach Loop:**

```
for(Letter letter : name){
 System.out.print(letter .getCaracter());
}
```