# Array output? Java

Tags: java, arrays, output

I always get the following output, when I try to get an output from an Array:

```
test1.Buch@5ef4b65d
```

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong?

```
Buch[] buch = new Buch[30]; 

for(int i = 1; i < buch.length; i++) {
    buch[i] = new Buch();

    char reply;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // input data into the Array            
    //.....

    System.out.println(buch[i]);
```

Comment: `System.out.println(buch[i].getXxx())`

Comment: Override the toString method from Object class in Buch class. info [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to ovveride the `toString()`  method in your class  `Buch`.

As per docs of [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So

`test1.Buch@5ef4b65d`  is the textual representation of `Buch` class.

You just ovveride `toString` method in `Buch` class.

To get the required output override `toString()`  like

```
class Buch{
    @Override
            public String toString() {
                 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                 result.append(this.name );
                 // append other properties too.
                 return result.toString();
            }
}
```

If you are simply printing a specific property of `Buch` class

```
System.out.println(buch[i].propertyname);
```

or

```
  System.out.println(buch[i].getProeprtyName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `toString` method in your Buch clas to get the output in a pretty way.

When an object is printed using sysout, its `toString` method is called. If `toString` method is not overridden in the class, then its default implementation will be used. Default implementation of an object `toString` method prints the class name and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object separated by `@` symbol.

**Note:** Most of the IDEs provide a way to auto- generate the toString method.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `toString` method inherited from Object class. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)