# What is toString in java

Tags: java

```
What is the function of  toString in here?
what is the need for toString
```

can anyone please explain what toString suppose to do here. I am new in java and learning alot of new stuff

```
public class Employee  
    {
       private String name;
       private String address;
       private int number;
       public Employee(String name, String address, int number)
       {
          System.out.println("Constructing an Employee");
          this.name = name;
          this.address = address;
          this.number = number;
       }




     public String toString() //what is  this function doing
       {
          return name + " " + address + " " + number;
       }
```

### Heading

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Comment: -1 because you could have found it in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Employee coolDude = new Employee("Billy Bob McCool", "123 Main Str", "867-5309");
System.out.println(coolDude);
```

Without the `toString` method you're asking about, this will print the class name and a hex number that will look like garbage to you, but it's actually the memory address to where `coolDude` exists in memory.  With the `toString` method, you can actually print something useful.  In this specific case, `"Billy Bob McCool 123 Main Str 867-5309"`.

Answer (score 0):

Method of Object class, which returns value of object.

According to Java Docs :

```
public String toString()
```

Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

> Returns:
>   a string representation of the object.

[refer java docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

from java doc

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
 * {@code toString} method returns a string that
 * "textually represents" this object. The result should
 * be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a
 * person to read.
 * It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
 * <p>
 * The {@code toString} method for class {@code Object}
 * returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
 * object is an instance, the at-sign character `{@code @}', and
 * the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
 * object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
 * value of:
 * <blockquote>
 * <pre>
 * getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
 * </pre></blockquote>
 *
 * @return  a string representation of the object.
 */
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29