# Use of Spring ToStringCreator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, coding-style

I am working on a Spring project wherein I have a POJO class

```
    public class Owner extends Person {

        private String address;

        private String city;

        private String telephone;

            Getters and Setters 

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringCreator(this)

        .append("id", this.getId())

        .append("new", this.isNew())

        .append("lastName", this.getLastName())

        .append("firstName", this.getFirstName())

        .append("address", this.address)

        .append("city", this.city)

        .append("telephone", this.telephone)

        .toString();
    }
}
```

1. I have two doubts why a `toString()` method is being used here? What is its use?
2. What is [ToStringCreator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/style/ToStringCreator.html) method doing?

Comment: For your first question you can refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Comment: For your second question,the ToStringCreator class uses `StringBuilder` internally and formats the output based on the default `ToStringStyler` class which is `DefaultValueStyler` of `Spring` where it gives the output in the form of `[classname@hashcode 'key1'='value1','key2='value2']`

Answer (score 1):

As per official docs

`ToStringCreator is a Utility class that builds pretty-printing toString() methods with pluggable styling conventions. By default, ToStringCreator adheres to Spring's toString() styling conventions.`

It is a helper class for customizing `toString()` presentation.