# Array reference explanation

Tags: java, arrays

For the code

```
int []arr = new int[4];
System.out.println(arr);
```

The output looks something like

> [I@54640b25

What exactly is the compiler printing out? The memory address of arr? Unlike C, Java does not seem to equate the array name (in isolation) with the first position of the array.

Comment: A good question, but I believe it has already been addressed here. Possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, each object has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, and arrays are *objects*. The default is displaying the class name representation, then adding "@" and then the *hashcode*:

> The `toString` method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object

Try to print the following line and you should get the same output:

```
int[] arr = new int[5]; 
System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(arr.hashCode()));
```

Comment: and to add, arrays are objects in java unlike C.

Comment: Passing in arr as an argument to println() automatically calls arr's toString() method?

Comment: @Duncan, just to clarify passing any object in println() automatically calls that object's toString.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in order to print the value of array:

```
Arrays.toString(arr);
```

Using `System.out.println(arr)` directory will print use the default `toString` method which returns:

```
object.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(object.hashCode())
```