# How to retrieve data from linked list java

Tags: java

Hi, I am trying create a linked list to store some data. How can I retrieve the actual data from the list values and not the item's object reference.

```
public class myList()
{
    private LinkedList<Node> list = null;

    public myList()
    {
        list = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    public void addX(Node x)
    {
       list.add(x)
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

     }
}

public class Node
{
    private String x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public Node(String x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    myList.addX(new Node(x,1,2));
    myList.print();
}
```

When I run this it prints the memory address/reference instead of the actual values. What am I doing  wrong?
Example output: Node@838378c7

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code has numerous errors. It does not compile. Post valid code.

Comment: Print data instead of the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `toString` method on the `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
    private String x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public Node(String x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "/" + y + "/" + z;
    }
}
```

This example returns the x, y and z values with a "/" seperator between each. However, you can obviously change the return value of the `toString` method to suit how you would like your data displayed.

This [tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/209515-basics-of-tostring/) explains the concept quite well.

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` method in `Object` is

```
public String toString() {
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

which is exactly what will get printed. You need to override it in `Node` class to show your output of toString().

Answer (score 0):

The output you see is generated by the default `toString()`-method, to get an output format of your choice you need to override the `toString()`-method.

For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the `Node` class object which does not have a `toString()` method, and so it uses the the `toString()` of the Object class which prints the output that you see.

Override to `toString()` method and print the content in the the way you want in that method so that the output when when printing a `Node` object is as you expect it to be