# How to print multiple variable lines in Java

Tags: java, printf, println

I'm trying to print the test data used in webdriver test inside a print line in Java

I need to print multiple variables used in a class inside a `system.out.print` function (`printf`/`println`/whatever).

```
public String firstname;
public String lastname;

firstname = "First " + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10);
driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys(firstname);

lastname = "Last " + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10);
driver.findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys(lastname);
```

I need those print in a print statement as:
First name: *(the variable value I used)*
Last name: *(the variable value I used)*

Using something like below gives the exact result.
But I need to reduce the number of `printf` lines and use a more efficient way.

```
System.out.printf("First Name: ", firstname);
System.out.printf("Last Name: ", lastname);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question at hand has nothing to do with Selenium. Remove this tag (and the part of the code that uses Selenium), and you will get an answer instantly...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do it with 1 `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s",firstname, lastname);
```

Answer (score 18):

Or try this one:

```
System.out.println("First Name: " + firstname + " Last Name: "+ lastname +".");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("First Name: " + firstname);
System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastname);
```

or

```
System.out.println(String.format("First Name: %s", firstname));
System.out.println(String.format("Last Name: %s", lastname));
```

Comment: thanks.. can I integrate the lines together and print everything inside one system.out.println function? that's my concern

Answer (score 1):

You can create Class `Person` with fields `firstName` and `lastName` and define method `toString()`. Here I created a util method which returns String presentation of a `Person` object.

This is a sample

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = generatePerson();
        String personStr = personToString(person);
        System.out.println(personStr);
    }

    private static Person generatePerson() {
        String firstName = "firstName";//generateFirstName();
        String lastName = "lastName";//generateLastName;
        return new Person(firstName, lastName);
    }

    /*
     You can even put this method into a separate util class.
    */
    private static String personToString(Person person) {
        return person.getFirstName() + "\n" + person.getLastName();
    }
}
```

Person

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //getters, setters, constructors.
}
```

I prefer a separate util method to `toString()`, because `toString()` is used for debug. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615741/4587961

I had experience writing programs with many outputs: HTML UI, excel or txt file, console. They may need different object presentation, so I created a util class which builds a String depending on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have variable date , month and year then we can write it in the java like this.

```
int date=15,month=4,year=2016;
System.out.println(date+ "/"+month+"/"+year);
```

output of this will be like below:

> 15/4/2016