# How can I print this 2 Variables in the same println "System.out.println"

Tags: java

I have two `int` variables, `abdou1` and `abdou2` , I wish to print the values of these. I have tried below which does not work.

```
public class Math1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int abdou1 = 115;
        double abdou2 = 1122.176876; 
        System.out.println(abdou1, abdou2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation!

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to print multiple variable lines in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584563/how-to-print-multiple-variable-lines-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As printf method in java works same like C printf function so have to use format specifiers here to identify the data type.

```
public class Math1 {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int abdou1 = 115;
    double abdou2 = 1122.176876; 
    System.out.println(String.format("%d %f", abdou1, abdou2));
}
```

> You can use these Format Specifiers for different data types
>
> - %c or %C Display characters
> - %d           Displays a decimal (base 10 ) integer
> - %e or %E    Display a floating point number in exponential notation
> - %f          Display a floating point value in decimal format
> - %s or %S    Display Strings
> - %b or %B Display boolean values
> - %g (%G) float or double use %f or %e as required
> - %o int unsigned octal value
> - %p pointer address stored in pointer
> - %s array of char sequence of characters or String
> - %u int unsigned decimal
> - %x (%X) int unsigned hex value
> - %%  Display a % sign
>
> You can use whitespace characters which are
>
> - space ( ' ' )
> - tab ( '\t' )
> - carriage return ( '\r' )
> - newline ( '\n' )
> - ormfeed ( '\f' )

For more further explanation and examples with other data types you can go through this link.
[Format Specifiers](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/System.out.printf.htm)

Answer (score 1):

use a `+` sign and not a comma   `System.out.println(abdou1+" "+ abdou2);`

Comment: If the two variables are a double and an int (as stated in the question), that would print the sum of those two values, not both variables.

Comment: Thank you for noticing this I will edit this for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

you should use "+" operator. Since this is a numerical value, if you directly use "+" between both the numbers, it will sum up. hence use a string separator like the one mentioned below

System.out.println(abdou1+" "+ abdou2);

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`System.out.println(String.format("Int value: %d\nDouble value: %f", abdou1, abdou2));`

Answer (score 0):

`System` class holds a static reference to `out` which is of type `PrintStream`. If you see the signature of `println()` then you would see that it has various overloaded forms but each accepts single parameter. You can try like below.

```
public class Math1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int abdou1 = 115;
        double abdou2 = 1122.176876; 
        System.out.println(abdou1 + " "+ abdou2);
    }
}
```

Comment: i want if some one but number else 4 the code show false 
can you help me .

package javaapplication2;


import java.util.Scanner;
        
public class JavaApplication2{

   
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
                    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int abdou = 20;
        
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt() + abdou);
        
    
}

}

Answer (score 0):

**You can use printf or format eg**

System.out.format("index = %d and %d",i,j);

System.out.printf("index = %d and %d",i,j);

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple and can be achieved by using:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    int abdou1 = 115;
    double abdou2 = 1122.176876;

    System.out.println(abdou1 + " "  + abdou2);
}
```

The reason it works like this is that `println` interprets the object calls at first `String.valueOf(x)` to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`. Therefore, every parameter is treated as a `String`.

If you are printing objects of a custom class, you should override `toString()` to what you want to print.

Comment: This is incorrect for Kotlin, this type of concatenation is not allowed for System.out.print or System.out.println

Comment: Thank you but this post has been tagged for java. It was even written before Kotlin was released so I hope it makes sense for it not to be applicable for Kotlin.