# toString method is returning random characters

Tags: java, android

for some reason when I run my app, instead of getting the name of the lecture, I get a bunch of random characters that show up.  I'm not sure why though.  Thanks in advance!

```
public Lecture(String lecturename) {
    this.lecturename = lecturename;
    listofwork = new ArrayList<Work>();
}

public String toString(Lecture lecture) {
    return lecture.lecturename;
    }

    /////////// IN ANOTHER ACTIVITY   /////////////////////

    Lecture test = new Lecture("TEST");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And instead of getting a toast saying "TEST", I get whatsmymark.Lecture@41abcf8.  I have a feeling its returning the actual lecture object rather than the string.  However, I can't find out why cause the code is so simple.

Comment: Look into the toString() method inherited from thr Object class.

Comment: Note also, that you are overloading the toString method.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a `toString` that takes a `Lecture` as an argument, and calling `toString()` that takes no arguments.  If you change your method definition to have no args, you will override the `Object.toString()` correctly.

```
public String toString() {
    return this.lecturename;
}
```

If you do not want to change your method definition for some reason, your other option is to call your version explicitly, but I am sure you will agree this looks a little redundant.

```
Lecture test = new Lecture("TEST");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test.toString(test), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `test.toString()`, you're printing the *test object itself *, not a string representing the object. Because you didn't override `Object#toString()` (you overloaded it instead), your object inherits this implementation:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

And that's probably not what you wanted.

What you'll need to do is put the `toString()` method you have *inside* the `Lecture` class, and remove its formal parameter. Then it should work.

A good idea is to put the `@Override` annotation on methods you intended to override. This way if you accidentally mess up the compiler should emit an error/warning letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to change your code like this

```
public Lecture(String lecturename) {
    this.lecturename = lecturename;
    listofwork = new ArrayList<Work>();



    public String toString() {
        return this.lecturename;
    }

}
```