# An array of 25 class object

Tags: java, arrays, object, parameters

I'm trying to create an object of type quiz that can hold 25 objects, but whenever I print the array, I get a pointer location (random numbers "Quiz@471e30" ) instead of my string question.

Here is the Quiz class:

```
public class Quiz {
    private static String questions;

    public  Quiz (String ask){
        questions=ask;
    }

    public String getQuestions(){
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(String ask){
        questions=ask;
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class QuizTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Quiz[] z= new Quiz[25];
        z[0]=new Quiz("what is your name?");
        System.out.println(z[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Always remember to tag a language. I'm tagging this as Java for now. If I'm wrong please edit.

Comment: Why would it print your question? How would Java know anything about your question (or whatever else you're modeling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the `toString()` method, Java automatically prints out the class's memory address with `System.out.println()`. You can implement `toString()` or do this:

```
System.out.println(z[0].getQuestions());
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the method `toString` in your `Quiz` class and return the appropriate string to be printed.

```
public String toString() {
   return questions;
}
```

Of course this makes your `getQuestions()` method a little redundant, so you could also call the function inside `toString()`, or go with one of the other answers which explicitly calls `getQuestions()`.

```
public String toString() {
   return getQuestions();
}
```

Comment: Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your existing works, you will need to add a method call to the object reference. Something like z[0].getQuestion(). Alternatively you could define a cusom .toString() method to return the question.

Answer (score 0):

z[0] is the quiz object, while what you are trying to print is the String named questions. Try instead:

`System.out.println(z[0].getQuestions());`

Alternatively, you could override the `toString()` method, which would then print the questions if you entered:

`System.out.println(z[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the String being from [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which the Javadoc describes as -

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

You also have a `static` field which limits your `Quiz` to one (and only one) question. It should probably be,

```
public class Quiz {
  private String questions;
  public  Quiz (String ask){
    setQuestions(ask);
  }
  public String getQuestions(){
    return this.questions;
  }
  public void setQuestions(String ask){
    this.questions=ask;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getQuestions();
  }
}
```