# Arrays.sort() error in main

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So i have a program that gets measurements of rain from the user and stores it into an array with the help of a Class RainFall that just has basic set/get  mutators and accessors. My problem is that for some reason the program crashes on the Arrays.sort() line. Is it that i need to create a new method just for that line? If so what would that look like?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab7rain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double amount=0;//VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
    RainFall r = new RainFall(amount);//CREATE OBJECT
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);//ALLOCATE SPACE
    RainFall[] month = new RainFall[12];

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
     System.out.println("What was the amount of rain in "+r.date()+"?");//rain per month
     amount = kb.nextDouble();//gets input
     month[i]= new RainFall(amount); //stores amount into array slot
     System.out.println();
     r.setTotal(amount);//sends amount to method that adds them together to create a total
    } 

    kb.close();

    r.setAvg();//initiates method that divides total by 12 to get average rain fall per month

    System.out.println(r.getTotal());//print total rain fall
    System.out.println(r.getAvg());//print average rain fall
    System.out.println();//skip line

    Arrays.sort(month);//i want this to sort the array so i can
    //then print out the highest and lowest months
    System.out.println(month[0]+" "+month[11]);
  }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: lab7rain.RainFall cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at lab7rain.Lab7rain.main(Lab7rain.java:46)
Java Result: 1

Comment: You probably need to implement `Comparable` interface in the `RainFall` object

Comment: This is the error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: lab7rain.RainFall cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
 at lab7rain.Lab7rain.main(Lab7rain.java:46)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Then @nem has solved your problem -- make sure that RainFall implements `Comparable<RainFall>` complete with a sensible `public int compareTo(RainFall o)` method. Either that or use a Comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error in the comment section, you need to implement the `Comparable` interface on the `RainFall` class before you can use the `Arrays.sort()` method or use a `Comparator` as **@ElliotFrisch** showed you in his answer.

```
public class RainFall implements Comparable<RainFall> {

    double amount;
    // your code

    public int compareTo(RainFall r) {
        return Double.compare(this.amount, r.amount); 
    }

}
```

Comment: When i use this method i get a strange print out. Where i say  System.out.println(month[0]); or when i say (month[0].toString); It gives me something like @33tjh43. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` method for the `RainFall` class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Your class `RainFall` needs to implement `Comparable<RainFall>`, or you could write a `Comparator<RainFall>` and use the [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29) that takes that. For example,

```
static class RainFallComparator implements Comparator<RainFall> {
  public int compare(RainFall a, RainFall b) {
    if (a.getAmount() < b.getAmount()) return -1;
    else if (a.getAmount() > b.getAmount()) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

and then

```
 Arrays.sort(month, new RainFallComparator());
```