# Print only certain elements in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I've been given the following array

```
   tests[] b = new tests[50];
```

So, there are some null elements in this array and I don't want to print those in my array.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
     if(b[i] != null){
        System.out.println(b[i]);
     }
  }
```

So, this prints out '@251970e2' but I need to be able to print out each valid elements contents which should be like 'batman', 'joker', 'batgirl'

Sorry if this has been answered previously, I had a look but haven't had much luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `toString` method in your class because it is going to give you clear information about the object in readable format that you can understand.

The merit about overriding `toString`:

> Help the programmer for **logging** and **debugging of Java program**
>
> Since **toString** is defined in **java.lang.Object** and does not give valuable information, so it is
>      good practice to override it for subclasses.

```
  @override
  public String toString(){
     // I assume name is the only field in class test
     return name ;
  }
```

Comment: +1 for quote and it should be `@Override`.

Answer (score 2):

Override  `toString` method in your Tests `class` ..

```
class Tests{

  ..... your code

  @Override
  public String toString(){
     ... return the value
  }
}
```

Comment: I never see toString return void .

Comment: it does not print , it returns

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString()` method in your `tests` class.

For further discussion, see [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)