# Don't convert "null" values from Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have 3 generic arrays which all have a pre-determined size of 25. For example, if its only 5 actual values in the array, it will display those 5, than the next 20 as null. I dont want to display any null values. Do I edit something in the toString? My toString is

```
public String toString(){
  return Arrays.toString(container);
}
```

Container being an array object created from a constructor function. Here is what my output looks like..

[Picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylHbZ.jpg)

Comment: Please import the result in your post, don't use external link.

Comment: I don't understand how taking and uploading a photo of your screen seems to be easier than copy/pasting that one line of text into the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353491/print-only-certain-elements-in-an-array?

Comment: It's unclear what a "generic array" is.  Do you mean an array whose element type is given by a type variable?  Or perhaps simply an explicit `Object[]`?

Comment: Sounds like a poor datamodel to me. Either use `ArrayList` instead of array or keep a top pointer to the first vacant slot so you know which part of the array to print. Then there are a number of options for printing.

Answer (score 2):

In the following, I suppose your container is something like `Something []container`.

Pre-java 8 using `StringBuilder`:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (Something i : container) if (i!=null) s.append(i.toString()+",");
    return s.toString();
}
```

Post-java 8 using streams:

```
public String toString(){
    return Arrays.stream(container)
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .map(Object::toString)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solutions when I get to my laptop later on.

Answer (score 2):

The `Arrays.toString()` methods all produce a representation of the *whole array*.  If that's not what you want, then you need to choose a different approach.  For example, you might do something like this:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(container)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(Objects::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
```

Comment: I don’t really see the hacky part about it. At least not compared to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use java8 or later:

```
Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(container).filter(i->i!=null).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with java8 stream:

```
MyType[] array = Arrays.stream(originalArray)
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .toArray(MyType[]::new);
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```