# Creating and Accessing Vector class

Tags: java, class, vector

I'm trying to  read and transfer each line of a .txt file into a vector format. It seems like my information are being converted since `vectPers.size()` give me 21 which is the amount of people i have.
The problem is that when i try to print the vector it keeps displaying these wierd lines which account for 21 people

```
Personne@15db9742
Personne@6d06d69c
Personne@7852e922
Personne@4e25154f
Personne@70dea4e
Personne@5c647e05
Personne@33909752
Personne@55f96302
Personne@3d4eac69
Personne@42a57993
Personne@75b84c92
Personne@6bc7c054
Personne@232204a1
Personne@4aa298b7
Personne@7d4991ad
Personne@28d93b30
Personne@1b6d3586
Personne@4554617c
Personne@74a14482
Personne@1540e19d
Personne@677327b6
```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;


class Personne
{
  private String nomPre ;
  private double taille, poids;
  private char sexe ;
  private int numero;

  public Personne( String nomPre, char sexe, double taille, double poids, int numero) {
      this.nomPre = nomPre ;
      this.sexe = sexe;
      this.taille = taille ;
      this.poids = poids;
      this.numero = numero;
  }


    public double getTaille() { return taille; }
    public double getPoids() {return poids; }
    public String getNomPre() { return nomPre; }
    public char getSexe() { return sexe ; }
    public int getNumero() { return numero; }

    public void afficher()
    {
        System.out.printf("%5d %30s %6.2f %7.1f %s\n",
           numero, nomPre, taille, poids, sexe == 'F' ? "feminin":"masculin");
    }

}

public class numero3
{
    static int lireAfficher(String nomFichier)
        throws IOException
    {
      final int LONG_NP = 30, COL1 = 37, COL2 = 41,
                              COL3 = 51, COL4 = 56,
                              COL5 = 64, COL6 = 68;

      int n = 0;
      boolean existeFichier = true ; 

      FileReader fr = null; 


       try {
             fr = new FileReader (nomFichier) ;
       }

       catch ( java.io.FileNotFoundException erreur) {
            System.out.println("Probleme d'ouvrir le fichier " +
                 nomFichier);
            existeFichier = false ; 
       }

       if (existeFichier) {



          BufferedReader entree = new BufferedReader(fr);
          boolean finFichier = false ;

          while ( !finFichier ) {


           String uneLigne = entree.readLine();

           if (uneLigne == null)
                finFichier = true ;
           else {

                 String unNom = uneLigne.substring(0,LONG_NP);

                 char unSexe = uneLigne.charAt(LONG_NP);

                 double uneTaille =
                    ( new Double(uneLigne.substring(COL1, COL2).trim())).doubleValue();
                 double unPoids   =
                    ( new Double(uneLigne.substring(COL3, COL4).trim())).doubleValue();
                 int unNumero = Integer.parseInt(uneLigne.substring(COL5, COL6).trim());


                 n++;
                 Personne unePers = new Personne(unNom, unSexe, uneTaille, unPoids, unNumero);
                    unePers.afficher();

           }
          }
         entree.close();
        }
      return n;
    }


static int lireRemplir(String nomFichier,Personne[]pers,Vector<Personne>vectPers)
        throws IOException
    {
      final int LONG_NP = 30, COL1 = 37, COL2 = 41,
                              COL3 = 51, COL4 = 56,
                              COL5 = 64, COL6 = 68;

      int n = 0;
      boolean existeFichier = true ; 

      FileReader fr = null; 


       try {
             fr = new FileReader (nomFichier) ;
       }

       catch ( java.io.FileNotFoundException erreur) {
            System.out.println("Probleme d'ouvrir le fichier " +
                 nomFichier);
            existeFichier = false ; 
       }

       if (existeFichier) {


          BufferedReader entree = new BufferedReader(fr);
          boolean finFichier = false ;

          while ( !finFichier ) {


           String uneLigne = entree.readLine();

           if (uneLigne == null)
                finFichier = true ;
           else {

                 String unNom = uneLigne.substring(0,LONG_NP);

                 char unSexe = uneLigne.charAt(LONG_NP); 


                 double uneTaille =
                    ( new Double(uneLigne.substring(COL1, COL2).trim())).doubleValue();
                 double unPoids   =
                    ( new Double(uneLigne.substring(COL3, COL4).trim())).doubleValue();
                 int unNumero = Integer.parseInt(uneLigne.substring(COL5, COL6).trim());



                 pers[n++]= new Personne(unNom, unSexe, uneTaille, unPoids, unNumero);
                 vectPers.add(new Personne(unNom, unSexe,uneTaille,unPoids,unNumero));
           }
          }
         entree.close();
        }
      return n;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {

        int nbPers = lireAfficher("met_a14.txt");
        System.out.printf("On vient de lire %d personnes\n", nbPers);

        Vector<Personne> vectPers = new Vector<Personne> ();

        final int MAX_PERS=nbPers;
        Personne[] pers=new Personne[MAX_PERS];
        int nbPerso = lireRemplir("met_a14.txt",pers,vectPers);

        for(int i=0;i<vectPers.size();i++){
        System.out.println(vectPers.get(i));

    }
}
```

I was wondering if it is because i need to create a class Vector like my class Personne. But cant find any information on how to start it off.

Comment: You'll need to write a `toString()` method in your `Personne` class.  Currently, your program doesn't know how it should print a `Personne` object, which is why you get the "weird" line.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3615721 - some of the answers there explain it nicely.

Comment: Basically a redefinition of toString?  public String toString(){return String.format("%5d %30s %6.2f %7.1f %s\n",getNumero(),getNomPre(),getTaille(),getPoids(),getSexe()== 'F' ? "feminin":"masculin");}

Comment: Yeah, that looks good.  Why don't you try it, and see if it fixes your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `toString()` method in `Person` class to get a meaningful output. The value printed is from the default implementation of `toString()` in `java.lang.Object` class.

This page on [`toString()`](http://javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=B348447F54F77ACDF55AD621E11BEEB0?Id=55)  in JavaPractices should give you more information.