# Java Dynamic Client Web Service using CXF

Tags: java

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf =JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client clientA = dcf.createClient(wsdlfile);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
Object res=clientA.invoke("helloWorld",new Object[]{"Dog"});
```

It's giving me result like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@1332b63`
I didn't getting the original value, Its Apache CXF, so if anybody can help me for fetching the value from res in String representation.

Comment: Make sure you use the Comment feature, rather than trying to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are getting is the object's value, based on the default `toString()` [implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

A good recommendation for you is to override the `toString()` method. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java) for more information.

Or if you have any getters for the object, you could reach the desired values by doing `myObject.getValueForSomething()`.

Comment: I had used the toString() implementation techn. but its not affecting the code , I am getting the same result ....

Comment: @MindDots: I don't really understand what you mean. Also I fail to find where you try to print out the values. Maybe you need to share more code. Do you have any getters on the object on which you are trying to print whatever it is you're trying to print out?

Comment: the res variable of Object kind giving me value  like [Ljava.lang.Object;@190725e but i wanting the actual value not The hashCode representation of an Object...

Comment: @MindDots: Edit your question and put everything you want/think we need there.