# How do I print out values of an array list in string?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a class called Employee in which I created an `ArrayList`for in another class. I am trying to print the values of the list but they print each element's object reference. I forgot how to do this, I have tried looking it up elsewhere but can't seem to find an answer.

Here is the Employee Class:

```
public class Employee {

int employeeID;
String employeeName;

public Employee(int employeeId, String employeeName){
this.employeeID = employeeId;
this.employeeName  = employeeName;

}
...
```

Here is where I print my values:

```
public void printArrListValues() {

   for(Employee x: employeeList){

        System.out.println(x);
    }
//    Arrays.toString(employeeNameLst);

}
```

I did try using `.toString()` on x, however this did not solve the issue.

The console printed this to me:

```
binarytree.Employee@78da5318
binarytree.Employee@45858aa4
binarytree.Employee@425138a4
binarytree.Employee@625db8ff
binarytree.Employee@771c9fcc
binarytree.Employee@783f472b
binarytree.Employee@25995ba
binarytree.Employee@4774e78a
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Add `toString()` to `Employee`.

Comment: why not use `Vector` or `HashMap`. Its easier to retrieve random values in the collection

Comment: `Vector` has been superseded by `ArrayList` way back in Java 1.2.

Comment: @TheUknown I decided to use a `HashMap` instead, I did look at various alternatives but that seems the best as I can just use a `TreeMap` to order my key values and I wouldn't need the`Employee` class for any of it.

Comment: @ajb I know, I still use it though sometimes :)
@ jp24 Glad, my suggestion helped

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an object to `println`, eventually, `toString()` will be called.  Because you didn't override `toString()`, `Employee` inherited [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which is responsible for the output you see.

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Override `toString` in `Employee`, and return the `String` you want visible when the `Employee` is printed.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand what I need to do. Do I need to go inside my Employee class and then create a `toString()` method that takes an `Employee` as an argument then print its content using `System.out.print()`?

Comment: Not quite right.  Create a method with the signature `public String toString()` in `Employee`, no parameters.  Use your instance variables `employeeID` and `employeeName` when creating a `String` that represents how you want the output, and _return_ that `String`; don't print it.  The `println` method will print whatever is returned by `toString()`.

Comment: Yes override toString() and make it return meaningful information. Joshua Bloch even cites this a good practice as it makes your class much more pleasant to use, especially with IDEs and testing. Some IDEs like Eclipse will even provide tools to override it for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can override the method toString in class employee
2. or x.getter methods