# Multidimensional Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program using a method that returns the location of the largest element in a two dimensional array.

Example:

Enter the number of rows and columns of the array:

3 4

Enter the array:

23.5 35 2 10

4.5 3 45 3.5

35 44 5.5 9.6

the location of the largest element is at (1, 2)

My code is working, but I'm getting the output wrong. Instead of numbers I am getting some weird output with letters and numbers. How can I fix it? Thanks!

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class homework1a {

public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a)
{

        int total = 0;
        int maxRow = 0;
        int maxColumn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
                {
                        maxRow = i;
                        maxColumn = j;
                        }
                }

        int[] largest = new int[2];
        largest[0] = maxRow;
        largest[1] = maxColumn;
        return largest;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                //Create Scanner
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                double b = 0;
                //User input rows and columns
                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns in the array: ");

                int numberOfRows = input.nextInt();
                int numberOfColumns = input.nextInt();


                //User input data in array
                System.out.println("Enter numbers into array: ");
                //Create array
                double[][] a = new double[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                {
                        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
                        {
                                a[i][j] = input.nextDouble();

                        }
                                     }

                System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at "+ locateLargest(a));

                }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: Even there is a problem in your logic of finding maximum. You haven't checked for maximum value in inner for loop so you will never get actual maximun value.

Comment: @ Dipen_a  I tried adding an if statement but I think it's also wrong.  
if (a[maxRow][maxColumn] >  a.length)

Comment: @joseph: have posted solution for the same as answer check it

Answer (score 1):

Your method locateLargest() returns an int-array, which you are implicitly converting to string while printing it.

I think you want to display the row and cell numbers inside the array:

```
int[] largest = locateLargest(a);
System.out.println(String.format("The location of the largest element is at %d,%d", largest[0], largest[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

`locateLargest(a)` returns an `int[2]`. Arrays cannot be converted to strings natively, so the [default `toString()` implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is invoked on the array. The returned string representation does not contain the array elements.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/) might help you to print a helpful representation of the array. You might also want to print both values independently, not the array as a whole, e.g. like this:

```
int[] pos = locateLargest(a);
System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at " + pos[0] + ":" + pos[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To print Arrays use `Arrays.toString(array)` output will be like `[x,y]`

```
System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at "+ Arrays.toString(locateLargest(a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `locateLargest` returns an `int[]` which will not be printed out nicely.

If you want to keep the signature of `locateLargest` as it is, you could change your code in main like this:

```
int[] positionOfLargest = locateLargest(a);
System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at " +
    positionOfLargest[0] + "/" + positionOfLargest[1]);
```

This stores the result in `positionOfLargest` and then prints out x/y coordinates the way you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Hey for finding largest you can have your method like this.

```
public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a)
{

    int maxValue = 0;
    int maxRow = 0;
    int maxColumn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            {
                   If(a[i][j] > maxValue)
                   {
                       maxValue = a[i][j] ;
                       maxRow = i;
                       maxColumn = j;
                    }
            }
    }
    int[] largest = new int[2];
    largest[0] = maxRow;
    largest[1] = maxColumn;
    return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u should edit your **locateLargest**  as this:

```
public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a)
{

    //may be ur array is contain negative 
    //so u can not use zero as MAX it's better to use first array element
    int MAX = a[0][0];

    int maxRow = 0;
    int maxColumn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            {
                 if(MAx < a[i][j]){
                    maxRow = i;
                    maxColumn = j;
                 }
            }
    }
    int[] largest = new int[2];
    largest[0] = maxRow;
    largest[1] = maxColumn;
    String result="location of largest num =a["+maxRow+"]["+maxColumn+"]";
    return largest;
}
```