# Display not showing in data structure output

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public class Link {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkList theLinkedList = new LinkList();
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(3);
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(6);
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(10);
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(20);

        theLinkedList.display();
    }

    int floorRequested;
    Link next;

    Link(int floorRequested) {
        this.floorRequested = floorRequested;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Floor req: " + floorRequested);
    }
}

class LinkList {

    public Link firstRequest;

    LinkList() {
        firstRequest = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (firstRequest == null);
    }

    public void insertFirstRequest(int floorRequested) {
        Link newRequest = new Link(floorRequested);

        newRequest.next = firstRequest;

        firstRequest = newRequest;
    }

    public Link removeFirstRequest() {
        Link linkRef = firstRequest;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            firstRequest = firstRequest.next;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Requests");
        }
        return linkRef;
    }

    public void display() {
        Link theLink = firstRequest;

        while (theLink != null) {
            theLink.display();

            System.out.println("Next Request: " + theLink.next);
            theLink = theLink.next;

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public Link find(int floorRequested) {
        Link theLink = firstRequest;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            while (theLink.floorRequested != floorRequested) {
                if (theLink.next == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    theLink = theLink.next;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Requests");
        }
        return theLink;
    }

    public Link removeRequest(int floorRequested) {
        Link currenntRequest = firstRequest;
        Link previousRequest = firstRequest;

        while (currenntRequest.floorRequested != currenntRequest.floorRequested) {
            if (currenntRequest.next == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                previousRequest = currenntRequest;
                currenntRequest = currenntRequest.next;
            }
        }
        if (currenntRequest == firstRequest) {
            firstRequest = firstRequest.next;
        } else {
            previousRequest.next = currenntRequest.next;
        }
        return currenntRequest;
    }

}
```

When I run this file, I only see this:

```
Floor req: 20
Next Request: elevator.model.Link@1db9742

Floor req: 10
Next Request: elevator.model.Link@106d69c

Floor req: 6
Next Request: elevator.model.Link@52e922

Floor req: 3
Next Request: null
```

What could be the problem?
The next requests are meant to be the next request in the linked list (except for the last index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by default if you use "Next Request: " + theLink.next the JVM is using the method toString to transform the Link class to a String class.

If you want to

[How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

```
public class Link {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        LinkList theLinkedList = new LinkList();
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(3);
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(6);
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(10);
        theLinkedList.insertFirstRequest(20);

        theLinkedList.display();
    }

    int floorRequested;

    Link next;

    Link(int floorRequested) {
        this.floorRequested = floorRequested;
    }

    public void display () {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Floor req: " + floorRequested;
    }
}

class LinkList {

    public Link firstRequest;

    LinkList() {
        firstRequest = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty () {
        return (firstRequest == null);
    }

    public void insertFirstRequest (int floorRequested) {
        Link newRequest = new Link(floorRequested);

        newRequest.next = firstRequest;

        firstRequest = newRequest;
    }

    public Link removeFirstRequest () {
        Link linkRef = firstRequest;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            firstRequest = firstRequest.next;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Requests");
        }
        return linkRef;
    }

    public void display () {
        Link theLink = firstRequest;

        while (theLink != null) {
            theLink.display();

            System.out.println("Next Request: " + theLink.next);
            theLink = theLink.next;

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public Link find (int floorRequested) {
        Link theLink = firstRequest;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            while (theLink.floorRequested != floorRequested) {
                if (theLink.next == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    theLink = theLink.next;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Requests");
        }
        return theLink;
    }

    public Link removeRequest (int floorRequested) {
        Link currenntRequest = firstRequest;
        Link previousRequest = firstRequest;

        while (currenntRequest.floorRequested != currenntRequest.floorRequested) {
            if (currenntRequest.next == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                previousRequest = currenntRequest;
                currenntRequest = currenntRequest.next;
            }
        }
        if (currenntRequest == firstRequest) {
            firstRequest = firstRequest.next;
        } else {
            previousRequest.next = currenntRequest.next;
        }
        return currenntRequest;
    }

}
```

And the output should be like this:

```
Floor req: 20
Next Request: Floor req: 10

Floor req: 10
Next Request: Floor req: 6

Floor req: 6
Next Request: Floor req: 3

Floor req: 3
Next Request: null
```

You have just to put in the toString method whatever information you need to show as String.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Link` class needs to override the `toString()` method. String concatenation using the `+` operator is handled specially in Java, as you can see from the [`java.lang.String` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (emphasis mine):

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings. String concatenation is implemented through the
>   StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method. **String
>   conversions are implemented through the method toString, defined by
>   Object and inherited by all classes in Java**. For additional
>   information on string concatenation and conversion, see Gosling, Joy,
>   and Steele, The Java Language Specification.

When they are being concatenated, the `toString()` on the superclass `java.lang.Object` is being called, which is why you are getting that output.

```
public class Object {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
    ...
}
```