# java 2D Arrays - sorting and searching

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting

Recently, when doing an assignment for college, one of the things I came across was sorting and searching a 2D-array.
Using `Arrays.sort(example);` or `Arrays.binarySearch(example, "xyz");` returns an error:

> example cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Instead of binary search, I had to use nested for loops, though I would have liked to do it the efficient way.

Another problem I had was using `Arrays.asList(example).contains("xyz");`, which never seemed to work. I then used `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(example));` to check what was wrong. This is what I got:

> [[I@1575c7e, [I@795f24, [I@554210, [I@16433e4, [I@18ada25, [I@f7bd29, [I@a3cf3e, [I@7af3e0, [I@21151e, [I@1f194d9]

What is that and most importantly *what is the best way to get around these problems?*

And a follow up question - Why do some errors (like `example cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` only appear once the program is run, not when it is compiled?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you show some more of your code, specifically where you populate the array and with what

Comment: Sorting a 2D array makes little sense. How would you sort `{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}`? +++ *Instead of binary search, I had to use nested for loops, though I would have liked to do it the efficient way.* - Binary search is efficient, but only on *already* sorted array. If you add the cost of sorting, it doesn't pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Arrays`, except for `deepHashCode` and `deepEquals`, does not recursively operate on arrays.

Ex:

```
int[ ][ ] arr = new int[ h ][ w ];
Arrays.sort( arr ); \\ Sorts int[ ] not ints
Arrays.asList( arr ); \\ Returns List< int[ ] >
```

Sorting a 2D array with respect to the entire array doesn't make a whole lot of sense and you would be better off just storing it as a 1D array. The same goes for binary searching a 2D array.

If you want to sort objects there are two ways to do it. The preferable way is to have the class implement `java.lang.Comparable`. If you can not edit the class or want to provide multiple ways to sort an object you can implement `java.util.Comparator` and pass an instance of it to `Arrays.sort`.

In order to sort or search an array using `java.util.Arrays` the type of the object of the array must either implement `java.lang.Comparable` of you must provide an instance of `java.util.Comparator`. Remember this must be the same type as the type of the object found at the first level of the array.

Ex:

```
int[ ]       arr1 = ...; \\ Type of first level is int
int[ ][ ]    arr2 = ...; \\ Type of first level is int[ ]
int[ ][ ][ ] arr3 = ...; \\ Type of first level is int[ ][ ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**First problem**:

> example cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

The items in `example` should implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and override the method `Compare()` otherwise `Arrays.sort()` wouldn't "know" by which order to sort your items.

**Second problem**, printing displays as:

```
[[I@1575c7e, [I@795f24, [I@554210, [I@16433e4, [I@18ada25, [I@f7bd29, [I@a3cf3e, [I@7af3e0, [I@21151e, [I@1f194d9]
```

The class from which you instantiate the elements in `example` should also override the method [toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java) in order to get a nice representation of what you're printing.

Comment: But it can't as it's an `int[]`.

Comment: @maaartinus why do you think so? he's got an example that looks for `.contains("xyz")`

Comment: Because of `I` meaning `int` and because of `[I@some_numbers` being the standard `toString` output of an array. And mainly because of the OP writing about `sorting and searching a 2D-array` and `int[][]` is just an array of int arrays.