# Testing My Heap

Tags: java, sorting, heap

1.) I'm having difficulty testing me heap class. When I try to print my heap, it's giving me code instead of the array. I tried using toString() and DeeptoString() and neither worked.

2.) In my updateValue method. I realize that it doesn't know what to do once it's reached a node that has no children. It shoots me an index out of bounds. I think an easy way to check for that is to see if the left and right child index is greater or equal to the size. If it is...I guess I want it to do nothing.

Code below:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MaxHeap {

    public int[] heap;
    private int size;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MaxHeap testHeap = new MaxHeap(5);
        testHeap.add(5);
        testHeap.add(4);
        testHeap.add(3);
        testHeap.add(2);
        testHeap.add(1);
        System.out.println((testHeap));
        testHeap.maxHeapify(0);
        System.out.println(testHeap);
        testHeap.extractMax();
        System.out.println(testHeap);
        testHeap.updateValue(1, 6);
        System.out.println(testHeap);

    }
    /**
     * _Part 0: Implement this constructor._
     * 
     * Creates a new Heap instance initially capable of storing the specified
     * number of elements.
     * 
     * @param initialsize the initial size of the heap array
     */
    public MaxHeap(int initialsize) {
        // TODO: implement this
        heap = new int [initialsize]; 

    }

    /**
     * Provides read-only access to the heap's size. Size here is the number
     * of *valid* items in the heap
     * 
     * @return the number of items in the heap
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * _Part 1: Implement this method._
     * 
     * Adds an item to the heap maintaining the heap condition.
     * 
     * An item is added to the next available slot in the array, and then
     * bubbled up to its parent until the heap condition is restored.
     * 
     * @param item
     *            the new int to add to the heap
     */
    public void add(int item) {
        // TODO: implement this
        int parentIndex = (size-1)/2;
        int childIndex = size;
        heap[size] = item;  //put it at the end

        while (heap[parentIndex] < heap[childIndex] && parentIndex >= 0){  //check to make sure it's a proper heap
            int temp = heap[parentIndex]; //start percolating up
            heap[parentIndex] = heap[childIndex];
            heap[childIndex] = temp;
            childIndex = parentIndex;
            parentIndex = (parentIndex-1)/2;
            }
        size+=1;
    }       

    /**
     * _Part 2: Implement this method._
     * 
     * Restore the heap condition to a tree rooted at the specified index when
     * the left and right subtrees obey the heap condition, but the root may 
     * not.  This is also known as "Bubble Down".
     * 
     * That is, given the specified index, and the fact that the left and 
     * right subtrees are heaps (if they exist), ensure that the largest of 
     * these three nodes get's swapped with the root, and then recursively 
     * restore the heap condition for the subtree with the element that was 
     * moved from the root.
     * 
     * In essence, this method bubbles a value down from the root until the 
     * heap condition is restored.
     * 
     * @param index
     *            the root tree to restore
     */
    public void maxHeapify(int index) {
        // TODO: implement this
        int left, right, large, tmp;            // declare variables left child, right child, largest node, temp for swap
        int i = index;
        left = 2 * i + 1;           // left child
        right = 2 * i + 2;                  // right child

        if(left <= heap.length-1 && heap[left] > heap[i])       // find smallest child
                large = left;               // save index of smaller child
        else
            large = i;

        if(right <= heap.length-1 && heap[right] > heap[large])
                large = right;                  // save index of smaller child

        if(large != i)              // swap and percolate, if necessary
        {
                tmp = heap[i];              // exchange values at two indices
                heap[i] = heap[large];
                heap[large] = tmp;
                maxHeapify(large);}
    }

    /**
     * _Part 3: Implement this method._
     * 
     * Removes the maximum valued item from the heap and restores the heap
     * condition. If the heap is empty, this method should throw
     * a NoSuchElementException
     * 
     * This function is performed by:
     * 
     * 1. removing the root of the heap 
     * 2. placing element from the end of the heap at the root 
     * 3. calling maxHeapify to restore the heap condition 
     * 4. making sure the size is updated
     * 
     * @return the highest valued item from the heap
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if called on an empty heap
     */
    public int extractMax() {
        // TODO: implement this
        if (size < 1){
            //throw no such element
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        int max = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[size-1];
        size = size-1;
        maxHeapify(0);
        return max;
    }

    /**
     * _Part 4: Implement this method._
     * 
     * Checks to make sure that the *max* heap condition is upheld on a 
     * given array of integers.
     * 
     * HINT: Full credit will be given on this one if you implement this 
     * method as a *recursive* function. It will probably make sense to 
     * create a private method that takes another argument (e.g., the index 
     * of the heap's root) to indicate where the checking should begin.
     * 
     * My private method has the following signature: 
     * private static boolean check(int [] arry, int rootindx, int sz)
     * 
     * 
     * @param array
     *            the array of data to check
     * @param size
     *            the number of elements 'in' the heap (starting at index 0)
     * @return true if the *max* heap condition is upheld
     */
    public static boolean checkHeapCondition(int[] array, int size) {
        // TODO: implement this
        if (array != null)
               return helpCheck(array,0, size);
          return false;
    }
    //Helper method
    private static boolean helpCheck(int[] arr, int i, int size) {
        //Base case
        if (i == size-1)
            return true;
        //2nd base case
        if (2*i+1 >= size){
            return true;
        }
        // check if a parent's value is larger or equal to both of
        // its left child and right child
        else if (arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 1] && arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 2])
            return (helpCheck(arr, 2*i + 1, size) && helpCheck(arr, 2*i + 2,  size));
        else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            return false;
    }
    /**
     * _Part 5: Implement this method._
     * 
     * Changes the value of an element in the heap. And bubbles the value
     * 
     * @param index
     *            the index of the item to be modified
     * @param newValue
     *            the new value of the specified item
     * @return the old value of that item
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified index is invalid
     */
     public int updateValue(int index, int newValue) {    
         // TODO: implement this
        int parent = (index-1)/2;
        int leftChild = (2*index +1);
        int rightChild = (2*index+2);
         if (heap == null || index >= size ){
             throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();}

         int oldValue = heap[index];
         heap[index] = newValue;
         while (heap[parent] < heap[index] && parent >= 0 ){
            int temp = heap[parent]; 
            heap[parent] = heap[index];
            heap[index] = heap[temp];
            index = parent;
            parent = (parent-1)/2;
         }
         //We need to check to see if the children don't exist
             if (heap[leftChild] > heap[index] || heap[rightChild] > heap[index]){
             maxHeapify(index);
             return oldValue;

         }
         else return oldValue;
         }

     }
```

Comment: You haven't implemented `toString()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `System.out.print(Object o)` uses the parameter Object's toString() method. If you have not overridden this method to provide custom behavior, it will use the parent method (in this case, the default [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)).

To print the value of `MaxHeap`, override it's `toString` method, returning a String that you want to represent an instance of this class. For instance:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return java.util.Arrays.toString(heap);
}
```

Comment: It fixes one of my problems. I'm still looking for a solution to my update method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what's wrong with my updateValue. I created another if statement to check if the index value of the left and right child were within bounds. Thanks for all your help.