# About calling subclass methods in Java

Tags: java

the code below is from the textbook :

```
CommissionEmployee3 commissionEmployee = new CommissionEmployee3(
"Sue", "Jones", "222-22-2222", 10000, .06 );

BasePlusCommissionEmployee4 basePlusCommissionEmployee =
new BasePlusCommissionEmployee4(
"Bob", "Lewis", "333-33-3333", 5000, .04, 300 );

System.out.printf( "%s %s:\n\n%s\n\n",
"Call CommissionEmployee3's toString with superclass reference ",
"to superclass object", commissionEmployee.toString() );

System.out.printf( "%s %s:\n\n%s\n\n",
"Call BasePlusCommissionEmployee4's toString with subclass",
"reference to subclass object",
basePlusCommissionEmployee.toString() );

CommissionEmployee3 commissionEmployee2 =
basePlusCommissionEmployee;

System.out.printf( "%s %s:\n\n%s\n",
"Call BasePlusCommissionEmployee4's toString with superclass",
"reference to subclass object", commissionEmployee2.toString() );
```

I want to ask why it can use "commissionEmployee2.toString()"?

Does't the compiler get errors?

Comment: `toString()` is a method that is inherited by every Java objects (it is defined in `Object`, the superclass of all classes)

Answer (score 2):

Compiler error occurs if the class doesn't have that method. But the `commissionEmployee2` using super classes method which Object class.

[`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)  method belongs to [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class which is super class of all Java classes, hence the no error.

If you override it in your class, it executes that over-ridden implementation otherwise the default implementation from Object class.

Comment: Could I also ask why the textbook says commissionEmployee2.toString() actually calls subclass BasePlusCommissionEmployee4's toString method?

Comment: Does what commissionEmployee2.toString() really calls is its class method, not subclass method, and I have to downcast superclass variable from superclass type to subclass type in order to call subclass method?

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` method is defined in Object class which is super class of all Java classes. you can override in your class for your requirement otherwise default implementation is provided by `Object` class.

How to use  [toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: Does what commissionEmployee2.toString() really calls is its class method, not subclass method, and I have to downcast superclass variable from superclass type to subclass type in order to call subclass method?