# Trying to print object through toString()

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to print the individual objects in the players class(performance, injured and name) and on the main class I am trying to print the entire player object  however when I try executing the toString(); method on both classes, I just receive player@2eb3998c or Main@37e6e526. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**Player class:**

```
  package com.laurens;

/**
* Created by laurensvanoorschot on 20-01-16.
*/
 public class player {
 private String name;
 private int performance;
 private boolean injured;

    public  player(int performance, boolean injured, String name) {
    this.injured = injured;
    this.name = name;
    this.performance = performance;
}

public boolean isInjured() {
    return injured;
}

public void setInjured(boolean injured) {
    this.injured = injured;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPerformance() {
    return performance;
}

public void setPerformance(int performance) {
    this.performance = performance;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.laurens.player{" +
            "injured=" + injured +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", performance=" + performance +
            '}';
}
 }
```

**main Class:**

```
  package com.laurens;
  public class Main {
    private player player;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    player player = new player (4, true, "laurens");
    player.toString();
}


public com.laurens.player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}

public void setPlayer (int performance, String name) {
    if (performance < 4) {

        boolean injured = true;


    }



}
}
```

Comment: You should really name your classes with an uppercase letter at the start, so it would be `Player` in this case. Makes it much easier to tell when you're invoking a static method on the class vs an instance method on an object...

Comment: The `Main` is just broken and looks like some copypasta.

Comment: Yes, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you simply forgot to recompile your classes; your `Player` code is fine (and you have errors in your `Main` class that you aren't aware of, which suggests no recompile). That said, there's nothing in your posted code that actually prints *anything*. `System.out.println` (actually, any `PrintWriter` print methods) will automatically call `toString()` on an object, so there's no need to do that yourself, just

```
System.out.println(player);
```

Comment: How did you represent the gray background segment behind just your text "System.out.println()"?

Comment: @Perdomoff Backticks. If you want to see how formatting is done, you can click the edit link and see the source Markdown.

Comment: Thanks for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.out.println(player.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` returns a string/textual representation of the object. [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Explicitly calling print, displays your properties fine:

```
System.out.println(player.toString());
```

as well as:

```
System.out.println(player);
```