# Why the return value is memory address instead of actual value in Java?

Tags: java

I have this class in Java:

```
class Vis{
    private char tv;
    public Vis(char tv){
        this.tv = tv;
    }
}
```

and when I try to initialise this class, I did this:

```
Vis vv = new Vis('a');
System.out.println(vv);
```

But what I have is: `Vis@74a14482` instead of `a`.
Can I ask what have I done wrong? Thanks

Comment: And that is the hash code, not memory address

Comment: Read <https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-> and <https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-> and <https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString-->

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have a custom value printed, then you need to override the `toString` method of your `Vis` class.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java) for more information.

Comment: Your IDE can generate this method for you. +1