# toString() behavior of object when not overridden

Tags: java

If the toString() method of a class is not overridden (or overloaded), and another method that returns a string is defined in the class, then what happens when I pass an instance of the class where a String is expected?

Comment: Try it. Is a simple and easy test. Otherwise read the documentation.

Comment: Seriously: do not write up questions for stuff that can be tested that easy. One of the core qualities of a good programmer is curiosity - the sort of curiosity that makes you **try** stuff. You learn programming by **doing** it, not by asking other people such basic things.

Comment: i'm in a hostel without a laptop and a computer with java compiler and i'm learning java out of curiostity out from a book

Comment: @karthikeyan If you can log on to Stack Overflow, that means you must have Internet connection. So why not downlload JDK?

Answer (score 1):

If your class extends `Object`, you will get the result of `Object#toString()`, which is what will be called. If your class extends something else, it will get the first `#toString` in the inheritance path.

Comment: not the string that the method that returns string returns

Comment: Don't downvote right answers. The answer has been updated and now is formally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using the name of the class where a String is expected is not allowed. Consider the following:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar {
  public void baz(String a) {
    // Do something
  }

  public void binky() {
    baz(Foo); // Compiler error
  }
}
```

However, you could do the following:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar {
  public void baz(String a) {

  }

  public void binky() {
    Foo b = new Foo();
    baz(b.toString());
  }
}
```

Because the .toString() method of class Foo is not overridden, **you will inherit the default .toString() from the Object class**. This default behavior will print a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character @', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. (Thanks Kevin!)

Comment: `The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character @', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.` It´s not a memory adress. from the documentation of `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact: It takes less time to test this than asking a question on Stack Overflow and getting an answer.

As you may know, every single class you create directly or indirectly inherits from the almighty `Object` class! If you don't override `toString`, calling `toString` will result in a call to the `toString` method of the nearest ancestor.

Suppose `A` inherits from `B` which inherits from `C` which inherits from `D`. Only `C` has overridden `toString`.

```
Calling toString on an object of...            will result in calling the toString of...
A                                             C
B                                             C
C                                             C
D                                             Object
```

I hope you understand that.

Actually, not only does the `toString` behave like this. *Every method does this as well!*

Now that you know `Object.toString` will be called. What does it do actually?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615757/5133585), we know that `Object.toString` outputs something like this:

```
FullyQualifiedNameOfYourClass@12345
```

`FullyQualifiedNameOfYourClass` basically means your class name, followed by the package that it is in e.g. `com.example.MyClass`.

`12345` is the hashcode of the object, returned by `hashCode()` on the object.

So will `Object.toString` call one of your class' methods that returns a string, if you ever declared one?

Nope. Because it just doesn't. The documentation of `toString` clearly says that it just returns something like `FullyQualifiedNameOfYourClass@12345` and nothing else.

Even if it did, it makes no sense. What if you declared two methods that return a string? Which one should it choose? Also, reflection takes time and will slow down the whole thing.