# Parsing JSON File to Java with GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to `parse` a `JSON` file to Java with `GSON` and i have problem

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Person p1 = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("/Users/blabla/Desktop/person.json"), Person.class);
System.out.println(p1);
```

This is my Person class

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> Friends; 

    //Getters and setters
```

This is my JSON File

```
{
  "Name":"TEXT",
  "Weight":95,
  "Height":1.87,
  "Friends":[
    "FRIEND1",
    "FRIEND2",
    "FRIEND3"
  ]
}
```

Output is `Person@52b2a2d8`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your exception, you get

Comment: I don't get any exception but the output is wrong Person@52b2a2d8
Shouldn't be the output is .json file data?

Comment: unless you put the output or error or exception we can not give a good answer.

Comment: Output is Person@52b2a2d8

Comment: add  toString() method in person class

Comment: override toString() and make sure that key names in json map to attribute names in java class.

Answer (score 2):

naming matters.... you need to make sure `JSON keys` are identical to your class `attributes` (lowercase/uppercase) etc...

either change your `JSON` to

```
{ "name":"TEXT", "Weight":95, "Height":1.87, "Friends": [ "fRIEND1", "FRIEND2", "FRIEND3" ] }
```

or change your `Person class` attributes

```
private String Name;
private int age;
private List<String>Friends;
```

in addition you need to `Override toString` method in your `Person class` to get nice Print

e.g.

add this to your Person class:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return (name + " : " + age + " : " + Friends);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If Person class doesn't have toString method than of course result will like this.you need  override toString() for that.

You can see about toString() here [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

1)Your attribute names should match with the `JSON` values

2)Right click in eclipse and generate `toString()` method.

Ex:
    person class should be

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    List<String> friends

    //Getters and setters
}
```