# Difference between wrapper class reference and user defines class reference in java

Tags: java, reference, wrapper, hashcode

Suppose I have a custom class, say Test.

```
Test test = new Test(); // test is the reference.
```

Now when I print the value of test, it returns the hashcode .

Now consider,

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
```

When I print the value of `i`, it returns 10.

Can someone help me to understand what exactly is the difference here? I believe both are object references, but for wrapper class reference, it returns the value of the object it is pointing to.

Comment: `Test` doesn't override `toString()`; `Integer` does.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Comment: Alright, thanks Andy. So that means "i" returns the Integer instance itself with value 10. Is that right ?

Comment: @hotzst. Thank you. I was bit confused with the reference concept.

Comment: I have one more question to be clarified. Is there any rule mandated, that for wrapper objects we need to use .equals() rather than ==, to check if the values they hold are the same ?

Comment: Methods from Object class such as  toString(), hashCode() and equals() are overriden and based on the value which the wrapping class wraps. Considering functionality of those methods it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new class, it inherits the method `toString()` from `Object`. `Integer` class overrides that method to return the inner value.

Answer (score 0):

When printing, there is an implicit call to [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method.

By default (in for your Test class) it uses the one inside Object class. For Integer, it convert the Integer to a String in 10-base.

Answer (score 0):

Your Test class is using Object class's toString() method which prints hashCode. But for Integer class, toString method is overrided. You can see Integer.java [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

user defined reference is an object,if you print that object means you may get some hash code because every class extends Object class,so your also have the property (method) tostring().

Wrapper class wraps its respective primitive data type 
Integer i = new Integer(10);
and
i=10;
both same in value.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `System.out.println(Object)` (or, more generally, [`PrintStream.println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object))):

> This method calls at first String.valueOf(x)

[`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) returns:

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.

Neither of your objects are `null`, so the `toString()` method of the instances is called.

In the case of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString()):

> The value is converted to signed decimal representation and returned as a string

In the case of `Test`, unless you've explicitly overridden it (or a superclass has overridden it), you will call [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()):

> [T]his method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

If this isn't the desired behaviour, override `toString()` in `Test`:

```
class Test {
  @Override public String toString() {
    // ... Your implementation.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you print the object Java will invoke the `toString()` method. The default implementation of `toString()` available in Object Class. Object is the base class for the all the Object in java.

```
 public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

It will print the class Name with  full package path @ and HashCode of the object.

The test class doesn't override the `toString()` method. But all the wrapper class in java override the `toString()`.so when You invoke the Integer method it invoke the toString() implemented in Integer class.