# Need helping printing a recursion

Tags: java

```
BST(T[] array) {
    constructBalancedTree(array, 0, array.length - 1);

}
void constructBalancedTree(T[] array, int i, int j) {
    if(i > j) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (i+j)/2;
    Node node = new Node(array[mid]);

    constructBalancedTree(array, i, mid-1);
    constructBalancedTree(array, mid+1, j);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to print this out in the main. I have created:

```
BST<Integer> t1 = new BST<Integer>(new Integer[] {1, 5, 9, 12, 13, 15})
```

but when i try to print it out, it gives me a reference

Comment: You are not printing anywhere in the code.

Comment: Whats a Node here is also not defined. And where are you trying to save the result?

Comment: BST<Integer> t1 = new BST<Integer>(new Integer[] {1, 5, 9, 12, 13, 15})

Comment: that is what I have in my main and I cannot print out "System.out.println(t1);" it just gives me a reference error.

Comment: it's the default behavior of Object, override `toString()` in your class.

Comment: @JerryChin Still don't understand how to print it in the main..

Comment: @keving your code and explanation of your situation is obscure, all I can is to give you an advice, take a look at [how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java).

Comment: **Please read** [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate through the array to print the elements in it.  In Java an Array is an object so `System.out.println(t1);` in your case will print the reference to the object.  Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < t1.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(t1[i]);
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a for loop in the main.

Comment: I think OP means printing the tree after it has been constructed from the array.

Comment: Yes. Here is my full code if it helps: http://pastebin.com/9SYJ584f

Comment: @keving This loop is just for printing out the array values after you have returned the array from your method.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what your code is supposed to do. It doesn't seem to be storing the node anywhere. I would expect that `constructBalancedTree` should be returning a node shouldn't it? Something like:

```
class BST {
    private Node root;

    BST(T[] array)  {
        root = constructBalancedTree(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

    private Node constructBalancedTree(T[] array, int i, int j) {
        if(i > j) {
            return null;
        } else {
            int mid = (i+j)/2;
            Node node = new Node(array[mid]);
            node.setLeft(constructBalancedTree(array, i, mid-1));
            node.setRight(constructBalancedTree(array, mid+1, j));
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

In terms of printing the tree you have lots of options. You could add a `toString` method that recursive prints child nodes; you could use a Visitor design pattern to visit all nodes; you could have a method that gets the values as a list or stream:

```
class Node<T> {
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private T value;

    public Stream<T> getValues() {
        Stream.Builder<T> values = Stream.builder();
        if (left != null)
            left.getValues().forEach(values::accept);
        values.accept(value);
        if (right != null)
            right.getValues().forEach(values::accept);
        return values.build;
    }
}
```

Then you can just print the values: `System.out.println(root.getValues().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.