# Outputs in Java on creating an object of a class and converting it to string datatype

Tags: java

I created a class named `create` and its objects `ob` and `ob1`.
Then I used `ob.toString()` and `ob1.toString()` and printed them using `System.out.println()`.

I got some strange outputs.

`create@a267b0`,`create@9de93c` and as on.

Where does that output come from and what does it mean?

Comment: If you do not override `Object`'s `toString` method, that will be the typical print out of your custom class.

Comment: Then why these strange numbers and digits

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: Do those numbers refer to the objects of the claas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the hexadecimal representation of your two instances of your class `create`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of toString method defined in Object class. It simply return  the class name + a unique identifier (which is basically the hashCode's hexadecimal notation ).

If you want to provide more specific strings for toString method, override the toString method in your custom class and return more realistic text that describe the object)

Answer (score 0):

This is class name + @ + hashCode() which is default behavior of toString() method inherited from Object.
You have to override this method to get desired string representation:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return ... // put here what you need to return
}
```