# Storing and then Printing data to/from and Array list of a class

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

**Class File:**

```
public class Student {

    public String stu_FName;
    public String stu_LName;
    public  String stu_ID;
}
```

This is the code I wrote to get inputs from the user
    public class Main {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value for X");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Student> stuIDArray = new ArrayList<Student>(4);

        while (x != 0) {
            Student st = new Student();
            System.out.println("Enter First Name");
            st.stu_FName = sc.next();
            stuIDArray.add(st);
            System.out.println("Enter value fo1r X");
            x = sc.nextInt();

        }
```

When I print the size of the array after storing values using the above code, size works fine,

```
System.out.println(stuIDArray.size());
```

but when i try to print out the results in any of the following methods, it prints some code type format

```
for (int i=0;i<stuIDArray.size();i++){

    System.out.println(stuIDArray.get(i));
}

for (Student a : stuIDArray){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

**output :**

```
com.company.Student@45ee12a7

com.company.Student@330bedb4

com.company.Student@45ee12a7

com.company.Student@330bedb4
```

Comment: The ArrayList was not necessary to show a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify name of the variable you need to get data for. Below code is working fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < stuIDArray.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(stuIDArray.get(i).stu_FName);
}

for (Class1 a : stuIDArray) {
    System.out.println(a.stu_FName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would happen because when you are trying to print the student "object", it would print the string representation of the student object. 
What you need to do is to override the toString method in Student class with proper properties somewhat like,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [stu_FName=" + stu_FName + ", stu_LName=" + stu_LName
            + ", stu_ID=" + stu_ID + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to learn about `toString()` method. When you try to use `System.out.println()` on an object, its `toString()` method is invoked, and the signature you've been getting, e.g. `com.company.Student@330bedb4` is the default return value of those methods, as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). If you'd like a proper detail of each field, override the `toString` method in your `Student` class. For more, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)