# How to return String.format with arrays

Tags: java, tostring

When I print an instance of my class, the instance is referenced as "null" because I return "null", how can I format the toString class so it will return what I actually wrote in this function:

```
public String toString()
{
    System.out.print(this.coefficient);
    for(int i=0; i<26;i++)
    {
        if(degrees[i] == 1)
        {
            System.out.print(variables[i]);
        }
        if(degrees[i]>1)
        {
            System.out.print(variables[i] + "^" + degrees[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println('\n');
    return null;
}
```

For example, it has to return `"m1 = 13a^2b^3"` (it is a polynom)
but instead is returns `"13a^2b^3  m1 = null"`

Comment: Well, don't print anything. Instead; concatenate the parts you want to return and return the result. Returning and printing are very different things.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly printing each component of the `String`, concatenate them by using a `StringBuilder`:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    s.append(this.coefficient);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (degrees[i] == 1)
        {
            s.append(variables[i]);
        }
        else if (degrees[i] > 1)
        {
            s.append(variables[i]).append('^').append(degrees[i]);
        }
    }

    return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use String Builder .
Wherever you are using System.out.println

Instead of that

```
      StringBuilder temp=new StringBuilder();
      temp.append();// Add here the content what you are printing with Sysout 

       // at the end 
        return temp.toString();
```