# Writing LinkedList into text file via ObjectOutputStream but output is garbage

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I am getting an output error when I am trying to write the contents of my Linkedlist into a text file

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ValidMovesMatrix.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        oout.writeObject("--+ This will show all the VALID moves A* algorithm has taken to come up with the solution +---");
        oout.writeObject(" ");
        for (int matrixIdx = 0; matrixIdx < matrixStack.size(); matrixIdx++) {
            Object matrixShow = matrixStack.get(matrixIdx);
            oout.writeObject(matrixShow);
        }
        oout.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Output error");
    }
```

It didn't print the contents of my linkedlist and the output text file contained the following garbage:

```
¬í t _--+ This will show all the VALID moves A* algorithm has taken to come up with the solution +---t  {sr  java.io.NotSerializableException(Vx ç†5  xr java.io.ObjectStreamExceptiondÃäk9ûß  xr java.io.IOExceptionl€sde%ð«  xr java.lang.ExceptionÐý>;Ä  xr java.lang.ThrowableÕÆ5'9w¸Ë L causet Ljava/lang/Throwable;L 
detailMessaget Ljava/lang/String;[ 
stackTracet [Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;L suppressedExceptionst Ljava/util/List;xpq ~     t MapStateur [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;F*<<ý"9  xp   sr java.lang.StackTraceElementa    Åš&6Ý… I 
lineNumberL declaringClassq ~ L fileNameq ~ L 
methodNameq ~ xpÿÿÿÿt java.io.ObjectOutputStreampt writeObject0sq ~ 
ÿÿÿÿq ~ pt writeObjectsq ~ 
   bt 
AlgoSolvert AlgoSolver.javat backtrackMovessq ~ 
   'q ~ q ~ t searchsq ~ 
   t 
ProjectOnet ProjectOne.javat 
acceptArgssq ~ 
    q ~ q ~ t mainsr &java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableListü%1µìŽ L listq ~ xr ,java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollectionB €Ë^÷ L ct Ljava/util/Collection;xpsr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp    w    xq ~ $x
```

Comment: you should make the class serializable or put some code yourself to make it printable.. its practically dump its memory.

Comment: how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectOutputStream` write objects as a serialized byte code format, that can be later reread.

If you want a text output use a `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` and implement `Matrix.toString()` to write each `Matrix` as formated text.

Comment: @wazzza you can read `toString()` explanation in [another QA about `toString()` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3615757/4648586).