# Sending array list in a POST request using Retrofit sends the object with the memory address instead of sending the values

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a class:

```
public class PetModel{
    Serialized("cat")
    String cat;
    Serialized("dog")
    String dog;
    // getters and setters
}
```

when I do a POST using retrofit like so:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/pet/{id}")
Pets postPets(@Path("id") String id,@Field("pets") ArrayList<PetModel> pets);
```

In the logs I see the request sending `<package_name>.PetModel@cc49e70` instead of sending the values itself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using @Body?

Comment: Yes, same problem even with body.

Comment: please post here your response JSON here ......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow method, may be you will got solution

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
List<Countries> country = new ArrayList<Countries>();
country = FetchData.getAllCountries();
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
js.put("countries", country); // make sure the Country class overrides toString()

// set the response content-type
response.setContentType("application/json");

// writing the json-array to the output stream
out.print(js.toJSONString());
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server side code and can change it just add a viewmodel or something as a class containing the array list of generic type T. Then every where of working with arraylists use that.

There is similar problem when retrieving String type from server which can be solved same way.

Answer (score 0):

Override `toString()` method from your `PetModel` class.

```
public class PetModel {
    Serialized("cat")
    String cat;
    Serialized("dog")
    String dog;
    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cat " + cat + " Dog " + dog; 
    }
}
```