# Print Different Object Data From ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

Is there some way to print different data from an `ArrayList` containing different objects?
For example, I created two basic classes:

```
import java.util.*;

class Furniture{
    String name;
    int weight;

    Furniture(String name, int weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    }
}
class Resident{
    String name;

    Resident(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then I stored them in an `ArrayList<Object>` and wanted to print the names, by using declared below `printArrayList` method:

```
public class Main{

public static <E> void printArrayList(ArrayList<E> arrayToPrint){
    for(E element : arrayToPrint){
        try{
            System.out.println(element.getName());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception e: " + e);
        }
    }
}

 public static void main(String []args){
    Furniture sofa = new Furniture("Sofa", 5);
    Resident mike = new Resident("Mike");

    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayList.add(sofa);
    arrayList.add(mike);
    printArrayList(arrayList);
}
```

Now, I know that not all objects can have a variable name or declared get method, therefore I tried to exclude these cases by try/catch.
I also tried to exclude it by using fe:

```
if(elements.getName() == null)
```

Still, same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: You shold cast your object before accessing its methods.

Comment: Why don't you use the toString method ?

Comment: you can use `instanceOf` method to check if object is of specific class (like `element instanceOf Furniture`) or use `Reflection` API for checking class/variable/method existence

Comment: I would wonder if it's a good idea to have completely unrelated objects in a List in the first place. Resident and Furniture don't seem to have any reason to be in the same list. If they have, they should at least share a common interface (`Named`?), and you should have a `List<Named>`.

Comment: Your first problem is `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use a parameterized type. Rather introduce a specific interface (for example `NameAware`) that exposes the `getName()` method that your classes with implement. In this way you could rely on a common type.

```
public interface NameAware{
   String getName();
}

public class Resident implements NameAware{
     ...
     public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class Furniture implements NameAware{
     ...
     public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

And define your method as :

```
public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<NameAware> arrayToPrint) {
    for (NameAware element : arrayToPrint) {
        try {
            System.out.println(element.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception e: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should change your actual code from  :

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<NameAware> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: best would be to declare the parameter as `ArrayList<? extends NameAware>`

Comment: even better `List<? extends NameAware>` or `Iterable<? extends NameAware>`

Comment: @Lino You are right. But Is it not a reading overhead and a not necessary thing for the actual requirement ? `List<? extends NameAware>` would mean that we want to set some restrictions (as not adding element in the list) and opening the possibilities on the generic type the List. But it makes the code more complex to read and it is actually not a requirement.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic I fully agree to replace all declared type `ArrayList` by `List` in the actual code but concerning `Iterable` it looks like a premature code generalization. Why do we should make more abstract the `List` in the methods that consumes actually only a `List` ? Currently nothing requires it and introducing it would give the reverse feeling.

Comment: @davidxxx, yes, using `Iterable` wouldn't hurt but doesn't really help either. The method is basically about iteration so in that sense it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice would be to declare an interface with the `getName` method, and have both `Furniture` and `Resident` implement it.

```
public interface Namable {
    public String getName();
}
```

Then, use a `List<Namable>` instead of a `List<Object>`:

```
Furniture sofa = new Furniture("Sofa", 5);
Resident mike = new Resident("Mike");

List<Namable> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

arrayList.add(sofa);
arrayList.add(mike);

for (Namable n : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(n.getName());
}
```

Comment: Why did you even post this if he wrote: "Now, I know that not all objects can have a variable name or declared get method, therefore I tried to exclude these cases by try/catch. I also tried to exclude it by using fe:"