# output from the array list looks like address instead of data

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

a simple android program which accept a user id and user name, and store them inside an arrayList using a subclass called Student. There are 2 buttons, one of them record the information and the other one display them. The top button seem to work fine, but for the other one it display something that looks like the address instead of the actual data, what's the problem? Thanks[image: main code]
[image: class code]
[image: unexpected output]

Comment: Post your code here and you did not implement `toString` in your pojo.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: you don't have getter for name. It should be `output.append(studetnList.get(i).getName())`

Comment: Please paste code instead of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override Object.toString() in your Student class.

```
//Sample code
public String toString() {
        return "id of the student:" + this.id + ",, "
                + "name of the student:" + this.name ;
    }
```

For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: U r welcome @omoisama, If the answer is satisfactory then pls accept it so that others with the same issues can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

use this code for you funclist method

```
    private void funclist(){
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<studentList.seize();i++){
        output.append(studentList.get(i) + "\n");
        }
    }
```

this will convert your object to string or you can add

```
    studentList.get(i).toString()
```

instead of your code.

Comment: I tried this version too but it seem to be the same