# How can I use printf to print arraylist of different variables?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, arraylist, printf

I have an arraylist filled with different variables. How can I print this arraylist out to the console using the `printf` flag in Java?

```
public class mendietaRAL {
    public static void theArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Object> theList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        theList.add(123);
        theList.add("Java");
        theList.add(3.75);
        theList.add("Summer C");
        theList.add(2018);

        for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf(theList.get(i));
        }


        theList.remove(1);
        theList.remove(3);

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf(theList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the problem with the current code?

Comment: the current code throws an illegalformat conversion error in the console when I try to print the arraylist containing different variables of type string, double, and int @Mureinik

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: When I try to print the arraylist out using the printf flag the console throws an error because there are multiple variables in this Arraylist,  how can I print this arraylist to the console without it throwing an error @MortezaJalambadani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toString()` method to retrieve a string represantation of the objects you want to print to the console. Read Java documentation about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). In short here is what the method does:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

```
theList.get(i).toString()
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615757/5759072) will also give you a bit more information.

Another thing to mention is that you were trying to use `printf` method to log information about an object without providing the proper method arguments. Read more about `printf` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf). Instead what you should be doing is using `println` method to print your information as mentioned above in new lines, as this method does not take any arguments:

```
System.out.println(theList.get(i).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `toString()` for each element in `printf`, for example.