# Java print the Value List

Tags: java, list, hibernate, object, arraylist

Hello i m searching for solution to how see the valus exists at my list , 
code :

```
public Iterable<RfpActiveObject> getactive(){
    List<Rfxobject> rx =     rfx.findAll();
    List<Rfpobject> rp = rfp.findAll();

    Long compteurRfx =rfp.count();
    Long CompteurRfp= rfx.count();
    long TabMax = compteurRfx+CompteurRfp;
    List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    newList.add(rx);
    newList.add(rp);
    for(int i =0 ; i<  TabMax ; i++) {
        RfpActiveObject rf =  new RfpActiveObject();
        System.out.println("**** Liste "+i+"  :");
        System.out.println(newList.get(0));
        System.out.println("**** *****************");
     }
}
```

The input to my list is :

```
**** Liste 13  :
[com.pfe.backend.models.Rfxobject@2767bc, com.pfe.backend.models.Rfxobject@2389804e, com.pfe.backend.models.Rfxobject@31eda7ed, com.pfe.backend.models.Rfxobject@5ba91ebd, com.pfe.backend.models.Rfxobject@600898f3, com.pfe.backend.models.Rfxobject@fecef4c]
**** *****************
```

I need to get the real value not adress please what i should to do

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite the toString() method inside both of your classes - Rfxobject and Rfpobject.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: @GetMapping("/active")
 public Iterable<RfpActiveObject> getactive(){
  List<Rfxobject> rx =  rfx.findAll();
      List<Rfpobject> rp = rfp.findAll();
      
   Long compteurRfx =rfp.count();
   Long CompteurRfp= rfx.count();
   long TabMax = compteurRfx+CompteurRfp;
   List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>();
   newList.add(rx);
  newList.add(rp);
   
    Iterator<Object> ii = newList.iterator();
         while (ii.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(ii.next());}return null;}

Comment: but i have already the same input  please what i should to do

Comment: @Override
 public String toString() {
     return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
 }