# How to print an array?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to create an Inventory System with a GUI using JSwing and JAVA-WS in Eclipse and I am stuck on trying to turn the Hash into an array. I am in no way an expert in Java, so I came here to ask for help.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public InventoryItem [] getAllInventoryItem() {
    ArrayList<InventoryItem> items = new  ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
    InventoryItem item=null;
    
    for(Map.Entry<String, InventoryItem> e : inventories.entrySet())
    {
        item=new InventoryItem();
        item.setBrand(e.getValue().getBrand());
        item.setCode(e.getKey());
        item.setName(e.getValue().getName());
        items.setPrice(e.getValue().getPrice());
        
        items.add(item);
    }
    return (InventoryItem []) items.toArray(new InventoryItem[items.size()]);
}
```

But when I call the method:

```
System.out.println((inventory.getAllInventoryItem()));
```

This is what comes out:

```
[Lcom.lansang.inventory.fx.InventoryItem;@123772c4
```

I also tried:

```
System.out.println((Arrays.toString(inventory.getAllInventoryItem())));
```

But still, I dont get the elements inside the array. It only returns this:

```
[com.lansang.inventory.fx.InventoryItem@123772c4, com.lansang.inventory.fx.InventoryItem@2d363fb3]
```

Comment: That is just how objects print out if you have not overridden the `toString` method - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615757/2670892). Your InventoryItem needs a toString method.

Comment: You can follow this article to know about [How to Override toString Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-override-tostring-method-for-arraylist-in-java/)

Comment: I did overwrote it now on my InventoryItem Class:

with:

public String toString(){
        return code+" "+ name +" "+ brand + "" + price;     
       }  

but it seems that my client class for some reason doesn't detect the changes I  added and still prints out hexes. But thanks for the help! I've got something to worked with now.

Comment: You're trying to print an array via its `toString()` method, which you can't override. Try a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
(inventory.getAllInventoryItem()).stream()
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```