# How do I use Stack.peek to see an instance of an object I pushed into the stack in Java?

Tags: java, stack

Sorry, I just started coding and I'm trying to put an instance of a object into a stack and peek it but when I peek it, I think it's showing me the memory address of the stack item instead of the actual value. The dog class I'm using only one has one variable and it's name.

```java
import java.util.Stack;
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack myStack = new Stack();
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("jake");
        myStack.push(dog1);
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
    }
}
```

This is the output it gives me:

> Dog@5eb5c224

I tried messing with the peek function and trying to place it into another variable of object Dog but I couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: If you write `Dog dog2 = myStack.peek();` after you've pushed the `Dog` onto the stack, then `dog1` and `dog2` will both refer to the same `Dog`.  Is that what you're trying to achieve?  Or are you actually asking how to print a `Dog`?

Answer (score 2):

if you print an object in java it will call the `toString` method on that object to stringify it. The default implementation of `toString` is inherited from the `Object` class and will print out the class name and its reference as you see it. In order to obtain some meaningful output, you need to override the `toString` method on the `Dog` class. See for example [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)