# Keep linkedlist object different after concatenation

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi I am working on implementing a linked list without importing any Java library. I have implemented the following class. I have a couple of test cases to make sure that the linked list object does not change after append and insert which is failing. Can someone look into my code and what do I need to do to make the last two outputs correct?  Thank you.

```
class LinkedList {
    LinkedList.Node head = null;


    int size = 0;
    class Node {
        char value;
        Node next = null;
        public Node(char value){
            this.value = value;
            this.next = null;
        }


        public char getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(char value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public void concat(LinkedList otherList) {
        if (otherList == null) {
            return;
        }
        else if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = otherList.head;
            size += otherList.size;
        } else {
            LinkedList.Node current = this.head;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = otherList.head;
            size += otherList.size;
        }
    }

    public LinkedList append(char ch) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(ch);
        } else {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;
            temp.next = new Node(ch);
        }
        size++;
        return this;
    }

    public static String toString(LinkedList list) {
        String result= "";
        int i= 0;

        while (i < list.length()) {
            result += list.getCharAt(i);
            i++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public char getCharAt(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Node current = head;
        for(int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < size; nodeIndex++){
            if(nodeIndex == position) {
                break;
            }
            else{
                current = current.next;

            }
        }

        return current.value;
    }

    public int length() {
        Node temp = head;
        int count = 0;
        while (temp != null) {
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void insert(int position, char ch) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (position == size) {
            append(ch);
        } else if (position > size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else {
            Node newNode = new Node(ch);
            if (head == null) {
                head = newNode;
            } else if (position == 0) {
                newNode.next = head;
                head = newNode;
            } else {
                Node current = head;
                Node previous = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                newNode.next = current;
                previous.next = newNode;
            }
            size++;
        }

    }
}
```

Main Class -> See the last two system out statements where the problem is.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list1= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList list2= new LinkedList();

        list1= list1.append('t').append('i').append('n').append('k').append('e').append('r');
        list2= list2.append('b').append('e').append('l').append('l');

        System.out.println(LinkedList.toString(list1)); // tinker correct
        System.out.println(LinkedList.toString(list2)); // bell correct


        list1.concat(list2); // tikerbell correct

        System.out.println(LinkedList.toString(list1)); // tinkerbell correct
        System.out.println(LinkedList.toString(list2)); // bell correct


     list1.append('s');  // make tinkerbell -> tinkerbells
    list2.insert(3, 'e'); //bell -> belel

      System.out.println(LinkedList.toString(list1)); // printing tinkerbelels - should be tinkerbells  - incorrect
    System.out.println(LinkedList.toString(list2)); // printing belels - should be belel  -  incorrect

    }
}
```

Comment: Why -1 this question has all the details. Example of what I tried. What is working and not working? It is not a duplicate of any existing SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `concat` method should not link the first list to the nodes of the second list. Instead it should create new nodes and append those to the first list.

Before dealing with that, first some remarks on your code:

- `getCharAt` is declared as throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but it never does.
- `getCharAt` and `insert` have a similar loop to find a node at a given position. This code repetition can be avoided if you would implement a method `getNodeAt`. Then both `getCharAt` and `insert` can use that method. Also the `append` method can make use of `getNodeAt`, providing it `size-1` as position.
- As you maintain a `size`, you shouldn't need the `length` method.
- If `insert` is provided with a negative position and the list is not empty, it will throw a null pointer exception, as you will access `previous.next` while `previous` is `null`.
- `toString` calls `getCharAt` repeatedly which makes it inefficient: a list iteration will start for finding each character, which gives it a quadratic time complexity.
- `toString` repeatedly creates strings with `+=`. You can use `StringBuffer` to avoid this.
- `toString` should not be a static method, and should not be called as such from `main`. `toString` is [supposed to be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3615721/5459839) an instance method.
- You never use the `get*` and `set*` methods defined on the `Node` class. They are therefore not needed.
- You've designed the `append` method to be chainable, by returning the `LinkedList` instance. Then maybe also make the `insert` method chainable?
- As `Node` does not need anything that relates to the `LinkedList` class, it could be defined as `static`. And as your `LinkedList` exposes no `Node` instances to the outside world (which is good!), the `Node` class can be `private`.

Here is your code with the above mentioned remarks addressed, and the `concat` method updated so it creates new nodes for what is in the second list:

```
import java.util.*;

class LinkedList {
    Node head = null;
    int size = 0;

    private static class Node {
        char value;
        Node next = null;

        public Node(char value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    private Node getNodeAt(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (position < 0 || position >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid position given to getNodeAt");
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (position-- > 0) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public LinkedList prepend(char ch) {
        Node newNode = new Node(ch);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
        size++;
        return this;
    }

    public LinkedList insert(int position, char ch) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (position == 0) {
            return prepend(ch);
        }
        Node previous = getNodeAt(position - 1);
        Node newNode = new Node(ch);
        newNode.next = previous.next;
        previous.next = newNode;
        size++;
        return this;
    }

    public LinkedList append(char ch) {
        return insert(size, ch);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (Node temp = head; temp != null; temp = temp.next) {
            result.append(temp.value);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public char getCharAt(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        return getNodeAt(position).value;
    }

    public void concat(LinkedList otherList) {
        Node tail = head == null ? null : getNodeAt(size - 1);
        for (Node current = otherList.head; current != null; current = current.next) {
            if (head == null) {
                tail = head = new Node(current.value);
            } else {
                tail = tail.next = new Node(current.value);
            }
        }
        size += otherList.size;
    }
    
}
```

The main function should also change, so it doesn't call `toString` as a static method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();

        list1= list1.append('t').append('i').append('n').append('k').append('e').append('r');
        list2= list2.append('b').append('e').append('l').append('l');

        System.out.println("" + list1); // tinker 
        System.out.println("" + list2); // bell 

        list1.concat(list2); // tikerbell 

        System.out.println("" + list1); // tinkerbell 
        System.out.println("" + list2); // bell 


        list1.append('s');  // make tinkerbell -> tinkerbells
        list2.insert(3, 'e'); //bell -> belel

        System.out.println("" + list1); // tinkerbells
        System.out.println("" + list2); // belel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These erroneous prints are occurring because of the way you have done the concatenation. In your current implementation, when you concatenate **list2** to **list1**, both **list1** and **list2** end up sharing the same **Node** objects for the elements of **list2**. As such, any modification to the **Node** objects in the part of the list that was originally **list2** will reflect in both **list1** and **list2** because they are, in fact, pointing to the same sequence of **Node** objects in memory.

To fix this issue, you would need to edit your concatenation function such that when you concatenate two lists, you create new **Node** objects for the concatenated part rather than reusing the same **Node** instances.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are concatenating the lists before the last two print statement

Before the concat statement , your lists would have looked like

```
List 1 ==>  t-> i -> n -> k -> e -> r
List 2 ==>  b-> e -> l->l
```

After the concat,

```
List 1 ==> t-> i -> n-> k-> r-> b-> e-> l-> l
                               ^
and List 2 ===================-|
```

Basically , you are expecting the contents in List2 to be appended in List1. But the List2 reference is itself concatenated to the end of List1. So the changes you do in List1, will be reflected in List2 reference as well and vice versa.

To fix it, you would need to change your concat statement to append the values in otherList instead of the otherList itself. Learn more about shallow copy and deep copy. [this link could be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy#:%7E:text=Shallow%20Copy%2D%20Reference%20variable%20inside,have%20reference%20to%20different%20object.)